# How can I examine contents of a data section of an ELF file on Linux?

Tags: linux, elf, objdump, object-code

I've been using `objdump` to look at assembly code in Linux ELF binaries.

Sometimes there is an indirect jump through a jump table that is stored in the `rodata` (read-only data) section.

How to get `objdump` or any other tool to show me the contents of this data section?

I could execute the program and examine the relevant addresses in the debugger, but I don't want to do that because it has to be done interactively.

The ideal answer will identify a tool that will not only show me the contents but will let me control the display format, much as `od` does.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
objdump -s -j .rodata exefile
```

gives a side-by-side hex/printable ASCII dump of the contents of the `rodata` section like:

```
Contents of section .rodata:
 0000 67452301 efcdab89 67452301 efcdab89  gE#.....gE#.....
 0010 64636261 68676665 64636261 68676665  dcbahgfedcbahgfe
```

It doesn't look like there's anything in there to control formatting, but it's a start. You could always undump the hex and feed it to od, I suppose :)

Comment: How can you get the data dumped in binary format from an ELF section?   Something like objdump -s -j -binary <section> <file> would be great.

Comment: @Bogatyr: cf. my answer.

Answer (score 52):

```
readelf -x .rodata hello_world.o
```

gives:

```
Hex dump of section '.rodata':
  0x00000000 48656c6c 6f20776f 726c6421 0a       Hello world!.
```

You should prefer `readelf` when possible since `objdump` simply does not show some sections like `.symtab`: [Why does objdump not show .bss, .shstratab, .symtab and .strtab sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160621/why-does-objdump-not-show-bss-shstratab-symtab-and-strtab-sections)

You can also extract the raw bytes with the techniques mentioned at: [How do you extract only the contents of an ELF section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925075/how-do-you-extract-only-the-contents-of-an-elf-section) and as mentioned [by ysdx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32138956/895245).

Answer (score 21):

You can get the RAW (not hexdump-ed) ELF section with:

```
# To a file:
objcopy file /dev/null --dump-section .text=text.data
# To stdout:
objcopy file /dev/null --dump-section .text=/dev/stdout | cat
```

Here I'm using `| cat` in order to force stdout to be a pipe. `/dev/stdout` might work unexpectedly if stdout is a file. `.text=-` does not send to stdout but to the `-` file.

However [objcopy and objdump have some deficiencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160621/why-does-objdump-not-show-bss-shstratab-symtab-and-strtab-sections) (because they are based on BFD which abstracts different executable formats).

**Update:** I wrote a [tool](https://github.com/randomstuff/elfcat) to do this which does not rely on BFD.

Comment: `--dump-section` is a bit recent. It was added at: http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/Commit-objcopy-Add-dump-section-option-td256052.html Why is it better than `--only-section`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视, well the `objcopy -j` creates a whole ELF file (which a ELF header, a section heaer table with a .shstrtab section, a program header table) whereas `objcopy --dump-section` dumps the content of  a section (and nothing else) to a file.

Comment: Very good solution. Additionally, especially for `.modinfo` section, to print each parameter and its value line by line, we can use `... | xargs --null -n1 -I{} echo {};` as each pair ends with a `0x00` byte value as inspected from original output. PS: It's my habit to use `-n1` but it's redundant in such mentioned command.

Comment: @hapor, it might depend on which version of sed you are using (?) but with GNU sed you can use `sed 's/\x0/\n/g'`