# How to extract only the raw contents of an ELF section?

Tags: linux, shell, elf, binutils

I've tried the following, but the resulting file is still an ELF and not purely the section content.

```
$ objcopy --only-section=<name> <infile> <outfile>
```

I just want the contents of the section. Is there any utility that can do this? Any ideas?

Comment: objcopy should work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather inelegant hack around `objdump` and `dd`:

```
IN_F=/bin/echo
OUT_F=./tmp1.bin
SECTION=.text

objdump -h $IN_F |
  grep $SECTION |
  awk '{print "dd if='$IN_F' of='$OUT_F' bs=1 count=$[0x" $3 "] skip=$[0x" $6 "]"}' |
  bash
```

The `objdump -h` produces predictable output which contains section offset in the elf file. I made the `awk` to generate a `dd` command for the shell, since `dd` doesn't support hexadecimal numbers. And fed the command to shell.

In past I did all that manually, without making any scripts, since it is rarely needed.

Comment: That would sound funny coming from me, but why not the straight-forward *proper* solution from @ndim???

Comment: If the file produced by the other solution is 0 bytes, just add `--set-section-flags .sectionname=alloc` on the command line.

Comment: good idea but it does not work for me.. see my answer which is similar

Answer (score 75):

Use the `-O binary` output format:

```
objcopy -O binary --only-section=.text foobar.elf foobar.text
```

Just verified with `avr-objcopy` and an AVR ELF image's `.text` section.

Note that if, as Tim points out below, your section doesn't have the ALLOC flag, you may have to add `--set-section-flags .text=alloc` to be able to extract it.

Comment: When I add this, the resulting <outfile> is empty. It contains neither the ELF section header nor the section content. The command I used in the question does not produce an empty file.

Comment: The following works for me: objcopy -O binary -j .text /usr/bin/lpr mylprtext

Comment: This neat trick doesn't work for all sections. `objcopy` will not copy out sections that are flagged neither loaded ("load") nor allocated ("alloc").  A comment in the source claims that "The contents of such a section are not meaningful in the binary format."

Comment: Strangely enough, but objcopy prints: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `elf.img', when objdump prints sections normally.

Comment: This alongside with the --set-section-flags allowed me to dump .ARM.attributes into a file. Wouldn't touch the awk script in the other answer with a stick ;) +1.

Answer (score 39):

**`objcopy --dump-section`**

Introduced in Binutils 2.25, and achieves a similar effect to `-O binary --only-section`.

Usage:

```
objcopy --dump-section .text=output.bin input.o
```

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/binutils/objcopy.html documents it as:

> --dump-section sectionname=filename
>
> Place the contents of section named sectionname into the file filename, overwriting any contents that may have been there previously. This option is the inverse of --add-section. This option is similar to the --only-section option except that it does not create a formatted file, it just dumps the contents as raw binary data, without applying any relocations. The option can be specified more than once.

**Minimal runnable example**

main.S

```
.data
    .byte 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78
.text
    .byte 0x9A, 0xBC, 0xDE, 0xF0
```

Assemble:

```
as -o main.o main.S
```

Extract data:

```
objcopy --dump-section .data=data.bin main.o
hd data.bin
```

Output:

```
00000000  12 34 56 78                                       |.4Vx|
00000004
```

Extract text:

```
objcopy --dump-section .text=text.bin main.o
hd text.bin
```

Output:

```
00000000  9a bc de f0                                       |....|
00000004
```

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04 amd64, Binutils 2.30.

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dump all sections in separate files.

```
readelf -a filename|grep "NULL\|LOAD"| (x=0;while read a;do echo "$x $a"|awk '{print "dd if=143 of=filename.section."$1" bs=1 skip=$((" $3")) count=$(("$6"))"}';let x=x+1;done)|bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another shot at the problem that uses only `readelf`, `bash` and `dd`.

```
#!/bin/bash

sections="\.symtab|\.strtab"

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage $0 [INPUT ELF FILE]"
  exit 1
fi

readelf -S "$1" | while IFS= read -r line; do
    pattern="\[[[:digit:]]+\].*(${sections}) +[[:alpha:]]+ +[[:xdigit:]]+ +([[:xdigit:]]+) +([[:xdigit:]]+)"
    if [[ ${line} =~ $pattern ]]; then
      sec=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      off=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
      len=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
       dd if="$1" of="$1${sec}.raw" bs=1 skip=$(("0x$off")) count=$(("0x$len"))
    fi
done
```

As you can see, I am using this to extract the symtab and strtab sections because they are impossible to extract otherwise (e.g., with `objcopy` and cannot be set allocatable).