# objdump to extract contents of text segment to a binary format

Tags: linux, objdump

How do we use objdump to output to a binary file?

This is definitely not the right way to do so:

```
objdump -s -j .text /path/firmware.ko > /content.bin
```

as it is only presenting text format. I only require the bytes of the text segment to be extracted and to be set in binary forms.

Comment: why not using objdump to find the offset and size of .text section and then dump it using dd?

Comment: actually, I am also trying to do in C system call, so it has to be preferably in 1 line if possible.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/696780/extract-the-contents-of-elf-and-write-to-binary-file || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925075/how-do-you-extract-only-the-contents-of-an-elf-section

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have to specify the file format explicitly using the -I.

```
objcopy -I #file type format# -j #ELF segment contents to copy# -O #data type to output, binary, etc# #input file# #output file#
```

eg.

```
 
objcopy -I elf32-little -j .text -O binary firmware.ko content.bin
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use objcopy instead

```
objcopy -O binary --only-section=.text /path/firmware.ko /content.bin
```

Comment: Hi, 

It states:

objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file '/path/firmware.ko'.

Comment: sorry i don't know your architecture but did you run the objcopy that is from the same arch as the .ko file?

Comment: The file format is "file format elf32-little". It was stated by objdump. Is there a way to specify this in objcopy?

Thank you, @tristan, for your patient guidance.

Comment: I see:

elf32-little
 (header little endian, data little endian)
  i386
  l1om
  k1om
  plugin

Comment: How about something like:

<pre>
objdump -s -j .text firmware.ko | awk '{print "dd if='firmware.ko' of='content.bin' bs=1 count=$[0x" $3 "] skip=$[0x" $6 "]"}' | bash
</pre>
?

but the syntax is still not correct.

Comment: I manage to get abit closer, but it's still text

<pre>
objdump -s -j .text firmware.ko | awk '{print "dd if='firmware.ko' of='content.bin' bs=1 count=$["$2 $3 $4 $5 "]"}' 
</pre>

eg.
dd if=firmware.ko of=content.bin bs=1 count=$[]
dd if=firmware.ko of=content.bin bs=1 count=$[fileformatelf32-little]
dd if=firmware.ko of=content.bin bs=1 count=$[]
dd if=firmware.ko of=content.bin bs=1 count=$[ofsection.text:]
dd if=firmware.ko of=content.bin bs=1 count=$[1101a0e102c0a0e1004025e90540a081]
:

and the 1st 4 lines is not needed. How do I filter?