# How to see the GNU debuglink value of an ELF file?

Tags: binutils

So I can *add* a link to a debug symbol file like this `objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=$name.dbg $name`, but how can I later retrieve that value again?

I checked with `readelf -a` and grepped for `\.dbg` without any luck. Similarly I checked the with `objdump -sj .gnu_debuglink` (`.gnu_debuglink` is the section) and could see the value there:

```
$ objdump -sj .gnu_debuglink helloworld|grep \.dbg
0000 68656c6c 6f776f72 6c642e64 62670000  helloworld.dbg..
```

However, would there be a command that allows me to extract the retrieve the exact value again (i.e. `helloworld.dbg` in the above example)? That is the file name *only* ...

I realize I could use some shell foo here, but it seems odd that an option exists to set this value but none to retrieve it. So I probably just missed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `readelf` directly:

```
$ readelf --string-dump=.gnu_debuglink helloworld

String dump of section '.gnu_debuglink':
  [     0]  helloworld
  [    1b]  9
```

I do not know what the second entry means (it seems to always be different). To get rid of the header and the offsets, you can use `sed`:

```
$ readelf --string-dump=.gnu_debuglink helloworld | sed -n '/]/{s/.* //;p;q}'
helloworld
```

Comment: The second entry is probably `readelf`'s attempt to render [the CRC of the debuglink file](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html#index-_002egnu_005fdebuglink-sections).

Comment: `readelf -wk` works nicely

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
objcopy --output-target=binary --set-section-flags .gnu_debuglink=alloc \
  --only-section=.gnu_debuglink helloworld helloworld.dbg
```

`--output-target=binary` avoids adding ELF headers.  `--set-section-flags .gnu_debuglink=alloc` is needed because `objcopy` only writes allocated sections by default (with the `binary` emulation).  And `--only-section=.gnu_debuglink` finally identifies the answer.  [See this earlier answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3925113/8316315)

Note that the generated file may have a trailing NUL byte and four bytes of CRC, so some post-processing is needed to extract everything up to the first NUL byte (perhaps using `head -z -n 1 helloworld.dbg | tr -d '\0'` or something similar).