GCC : How to generate separated .bin files for instructions and constant data?
I am working with a custom CPU that has separated instruction and data memories. This is a Harvard Architecture implementing the RISC-V ISA on a FPGA, so I do not have any tool to load the memory, I am "manually" loading it in the RTL.
I would like to get a .bin file containing the instructions only, and another .bin file containing the constant data only so I can load each one of them in the appropriate memory.
The architecture is similar to this one:

The data memory is a mix of ROM and RAM.
Is it possible to do this using GCC, and how ?

What exactly does that even mean, separate memories? Is that a real distinction at architecture level? In that case, GCC already has to understand the CPU architecture, and make such a split. But on e.g. an ARM system, constant data can be RIP-relative meaning that data has to be in the instruction memory.

Typically you generate one hex file, and then the loader or flasher or what you use loads all data in appriopriate places and addreses. The hex file advantage is exactly that it contains the addresses. How big is your big file? Do you know the offset at which constant data start? Just dd them out.

@MSalters Yes, this is a Harvard architecture for the RISC-V ISA.

@KamilCuk The thing is that I don't have any loader, this is a custom CPU designed on a FPGA. I should have put this info in the question, I'll add it.

Or also, i would generate an elf file, and then objcopy data out of sections.

@KamilCuk objcopy is able to extract a specific section of memory ? It could be a solution if I can separately extract the .text and the .rodata sections

I don't think RISC-V (the standard) is an Harvard architecture; the ISA specifies a flat address space. (Section 1.4, "A RISC-V hart has a single byte-addressable address space"). Of course you can make a RISC-V-like design, but don't expect a standard GCC to support your custom kludges.

@MSalters oh ! Is it some kind of Von Neumann then ? I am following a textbook about CPU design that explains how to design a Harvard-CPU implementing a subset of the RISCV-ISA. I am currently trying to complete the design but in this case there's no point to continue if the result would not be "RISC-V compliant".

@MSalters or if I add some kind of memory controller that redirects/controls the memory datapath depending on the given memory address, would it be ok as the memory would appear as a "flat address space" to the programmer ?

@Wheatley: The problem with implementing a "subset of the RISC-V ISA" is that a compiler will expect the whole ISA to be available. That's why RISC-V defines standardized supersets instead.  Yes, you can create subsets, but that makes you responsible for the associated toolchain.

@Wheatley: Modern CPU's often implement Harvard-architecture L1 caches. That's a tricky optimization close to the CPU core. But it shows the subtle distinction between ISA-level addresses and physical memory. You can definitely implement a page table mechanism where the physical address contains one bit indicating memory space. Still, RISC-V has 20 bit immediate encodings, and GCC knows how to use those. Some of your constants can very well end up inside an instruction. The theoretical Harvard architecture doesn't really hold up in the modern world.

@MSalters I mean, the book is implementing a subset of the ISA, my goal is to complete it to be able to run programs compiled with an already available toolchain (GCC in this case).

@MSalters I would like to be able to handle all kind of programs and data, even those that do not fit in instructions (such as strings). So if my understanding is correct, this is possible to use a Harvard architecture but it would require a lot of tricks and complexity ? Should I better switch to a Von Neumann architecture then?

Elf is native to linux, there are tools to work with then. An elf file has sections and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925075/how-to-extract-only-the-raw-contents-of-an-elf-section
