# checking if a binary compiled with "-static"

Tags: linux, gcc, static

I have a binary file in linux. How can I check whether it has been compiled with "-static" or not?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`ldd /path/to/binary` should not list any shared libraries if the binary is statically compiled.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the `file` command (and `objdump` could also be useful).

Answer (score 12):

**Check if it has a program header of type `INTERP`**

At the lower level, an executable is static if it does not have a [program header](http://www.cirosantilli.com/elf-hello-world/#program-header-table) with type:

```
Elf32_Phd.p_type == PT_INTERP
```

This is mentioned in the [System V ABI spec](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf).

Remember that program headers determine the [ELF segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361248/whats-the-difference-of-section-and-segment-in-elf-file-format), including those of type `PT_LOAD` that will get loaded in to memory and be run.

If that header is present, its contents are exactly the path of the dynamic loader.

**`readelf` check**

We can observe this with `readelf`. First compile a C hello world dynamically:

```
gcc -o main.out main.c
```

and then:

```
readelf --program-headers --wide main.out
```

outputs:

```
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x1050
There are 11 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x000268 0x000268 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x0002a8 0x00000000000002a8 0x00000000000002a8 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000560 0x000560 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0001bd 0x0001bd R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x000150 0x000150 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002db8 0x0000000000003db8 0x0000000000003db8 0x000258 0x000260 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x002dc8 0x0000000000003dc8 0x0000000000003dc8 0x0001f0 0x0001f0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x0002c4 0x00000000000002c4 0x00000000000002c4 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00200c 0x000000000000200c 0x000000000000200c 0x00003c 0x00003c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x002db8 0x0000000000003db8 0x0000000000003db8 0x000248 0x000248 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt
   03     .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini
   04     .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   05     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .data .bss
   06     .dynamic
   07     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id
   08     .eh_frame_hdr
   09
   10     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

so note the `INTERP` header is there, and it is so important that `readelf` even gave a quick preview of its short 28 (0x1c) byte contents: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, which is the path to the dynamic loader (27 bytes long + 1 for `\0`).

Note how this resides side by side with the other segments, including e.g. those that actually get loaded into memory such as: `.text`.

We can then more directly extract those bytes without the preview with:

```
readelf -x .interp main.out
```

which gives:

```
Hex dump of section '.interp':
  0x000002a8 2f6c6962 36342f6c 642d6c69 6e75782d /lib64/ld-linux-
  0x000002b8 7838362d 36342e73 6f2e3200          x86-64.so.2.
```

as explained at: [How can I examine contents of a data section of an ELF file on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685483/how-can-i-examine-contents-of-a-data-section-of-an-elf-file-on-linux/30452453#30452453)

**`file` source code**

`file` 5.36 source code comments at [src/readelf.c](https://github.com/file/file/blob/FILE5_36/src/readelf.c#L1581) claim that it also checks for `PT_INTERP`:

```
/*
 * Look through the program headers of an executable image, searching
 * for a PT_INTERP section; if one is found, it's dynamically linked,
 * otherwise it's statically linked.
 */
private int
dophn_exec(struct magic_set *ms, int clazz, int swap, int fd, off_t off,
    int num, size_t size, off_t fsize, int sh_num, int *flags,
    uint16_t *notecount)
{
    Elf32_Phdr ph32;
    Elf64_Phdr ph64;
    const char *linking_style = "statically";
```

found with `git grep statically` from the message `main.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped`.

However, this comment seems to be outdated compared to the code, which instead checks for `PT_DYNAMIC`:

```
    case PT_DYNAMIC:
        linking_style = "dynamically";
        doread = 1;
        break;
```

I'm not sure why this is done, and I'm lazy to dig into `git log` now. In particular, this confused me a bit when I tried to make a statically linked PIE executable with `--no-dynamic-linker` as shown at: [How to create a statically linked position independent executable ELF in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664494/how-to-create-a-statically-linked-position-independent-executable-elf-in-linux/55666943#55666943) which does not have `PT_INTERP` but does have `PT_DYNAMIC`, and which I do not expect to use the dynamic loader.

I ended up doing a deeper source analysis for `-fPIE` at: [Why does GCC create a shared object instead of an executable binary according to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/why-does-gcc-create-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary-according-to/55704865#55704865) the answer is likely there as well.

**Linux kernel source code**

The Linux kernel 5.0 reads the ELF file during the exec system call at [fs/binfmt_elf.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/fs/binfmt_elf.c) as explained at: [How does kernel get an executable binary file running under linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352535/how-does-kernel-get-an-executable-binary-file-running-under-linux/31394861#31394861)

The kernel loops over the program headers at [`load_elf_binary`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L751)

```
    for (i = 0; i < loc->elf_ex.e_phnum; i++) {
        if (elf_ppnt->p_type == PT_INTERP) {
            /* This is the program interpreter used for
             * shared libraries - for now assume that this
             * is an a.out format binary
             */
```

I haven't read the code fully, but I would expect then that it only uses the dynamic loader if `INTERP` is found, otherwise which path should it use?

`PT_DYNAMIC` is not used in that file.

**Bonus: check if `-pie` was used**

I've explained that in detail at: [Why does GCC create a shared object instead of an executable binary according to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/why-does-gcc-create-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary-according-to/55704865#55704865)