# Difference between Program header and Section Header in ELF

Tags: c, arm, gnu, elf, linker-scripts

Q1   What is the difference between Program header and Section Header in ELF?

Q1.1 What is the difference between segment and a section?

I believe pheaders point to sections only.

Q2. What is the difference between File Header and Program Header?

As per GNU ld linker script, [Using Id: The GNU Linker](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/pdf/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-4-Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker-en-US.pdf):

```
PHDRS
{
name type [ FILEHDR ] [ PHDRS ] [ AT ( address ) ]
[ FLAGS ( flags ) ] ;
}
```

> You may use the FILEHDR and PHDRS keywords appear after the program header type to further
> describe the contents of the segment. The FILEHDR keyword means that the segment should include
> the ELF file header. The PHDRS keyword means that the segment should include the ELF program
> headers themselves.

This is a bit confusing.

Comment: Section vs segment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361248/whats-the-difference-of-section-and-segment-in-elf-file-format

Answer (score 29):

The [Executable & Linkable Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) *wikipage* has a nice picture explaining ELF, and the difference between its program header & sections header. See also [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)

The [initial] program header is defining segments (in the [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) of a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) running that ELF executable) projected in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (the executable point of view) at [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) time. The [final] sections header is defining sections (the linkable point of view, for [ld(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) etc...). Each section belongs to a segment (and may, or not, be visible -i.e. mapped into memory- at execution time). The ELF file header tells where program header table & section header table are.

Use also [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) and [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) to explore several ELF files (executables, shared objects, linkable objects) existing on your Linux system.

Levine's [Linkers & Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linkers/) book has a chapter explaining that in details.

And Drepper's paper [How to Write Shared Libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) also has some good explanation.

Comment: But my answer still fits. Read & follow carefully the links.

Comment: Dear Basile, It doesnt say much about Program header. I am looking for detail on usage of PHDRS
{
name type [ FILEHDR ] [ PHDRS ] [ AT ( address ) ]
[ FLAGS ( flags ) ] ;
}

Comment: Summary: *run time* and *load time*.  Non-allocated sections (debug info), BSS sections not in the ELF, but allocated at run-time (NOLOAD).  Similar concepts/keywords are *VMA* and *LMA*.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 What is the difference between the Program header and the Section Header in ELF?

- A program header describes a segment or other information that the system needs to prepare the program for execution.
- A section is an interface that can represent a lot of things. Look [here for details](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/6m7qcoblj/index.html#chapter6-18048) (search for `Elf64_Shdr`)
- A section header is inside a segment.

Q1.1 What is the difference between a segment and a section?

- A segment consists of one or more sections, though this fact is transparent to the program header.

Q2. What is the difference between File Header and Program Header?

- The ELF file header.  This appears at the start of every ELF file (see `/usr/include/elf.h`). It also has the number of program headers existing in this file.
- The ELF file always starts with the ELF file header. And it references the program headers. You need at least one program header.