# Why an ELF executable could have 4 LOAD segments?

Tags: unix, linker, llvm, ld, elf

There is a remote 64-bit *nix server that can compile a user-provided code (which should be written in Rust, but I don't think it matters since it uses LLVM). I don't know which compiler/linker flags it uses, but the compiled ELF executable looks weird - it has 4 LOAD segments:

```
$ readelf -e executable
...
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
...
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000004138 0x0000000000004138  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000005000 0x0000000000005000 0x0000000000005000
                 0x00000000000305e9 0x00000000000305e9  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000036000 0x0000000000036000 0x0000000000036000
                 0x000000000000d808 0x000000000000d808  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000043da0 0x0000000000044da0 0x0000000000044da0
                 0x0000000000002290 0x00000000000024a0  RW     0x1000
...
```

On my own system all executables that I was looking at only have 2 LOAD segments:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
...
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000003000c0 0x00000000003000c0  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x00000000003002b0 0x00000000005002b0 0x00000000005002b0
                 0x00000000000776c8 0x000000000009b200  RW     0x200000
...
```

1. What are the circumstances (compiler/linker versions, flags etc) under which a compiler might build an ELF with 4 LOAD segments?
2. What is the point of having 4 LOAD segments? I imagine that having a segment with read but not execute permission might help against certain exploits, but why have two such segments?

Comment: Found part of the answer: lld links with 3 segments by default (R, R+E and R+W).

Comment: GNU Binutils `ld` does this for C programs, too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A typical BFD-ld or Gold linked Linux executable has 2 loadable segments, with the `ELF` header merged with `.text` and `.rodata` into the first `RE` segment, and `.data`, `.bss` and other writable sections merged into the second `RW` segment.

Here is the typical section to segment mapping:

```
$ echo "int foo; int main() { return 0;}"  | clang -xc - -o a.out-gold -fuse-ld=gold
$ readelf -Wl a.out-gold

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x400420
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040 0x0001f8 0x0001f8 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x0006b0 0x0006b0 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x000e18 0x0000000000401e18 0x0000000000401e18 0x0001f8 0x000200 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x000e28 0x0000000000401e28 0x0000000000401e28 0x0001b0 0x0001b0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00067c 0x000000000040067c 0x000000000040067c 0x000034 0x000034 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000e18 0x0000000000401e18 0x0000000000401e18 0x0001e8 0x0001e8 RW  0x8

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.hash .hash .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .init .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame .eh_frame_hdr
   03     .fini_array .init_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
   04     .dynamic
   05     .note.ABI-tag
   06     .eh_frame_hdr
   07
   08     .fini_array .init_array .dynamic .got .got.plt
```

This optimizes the number of `mmap`s that the kernel must perform to load such executable, but at a security cost: the data in `.rodata` shouldn't be executable, but is (because it's merged with `.text`, which must be executable). This may significantly increase the attack surface for someone trying to hijack a process.

Newer Linux systems, in particular using `LLD` to link binaries, prioritize security over speed, and put ELF header and `.rodata` into the first `R`-only segment, resulting in 3 load segments and improved security. Here is a typical mapping:

```
$ echo "int foo; int main() { return 0;}"  | clang -xc - -o a.out-lld -fuse-ld=lld
$ readelf -Wl a.out-lld

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x201000
There are 10 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000200040 0x0000000000200040 0x000230 0x000230 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x000270 0x0000000000200270 0x0000000000200270 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000200000 0x0000000000200000 0x000558 0x000558 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000201000 0x0000000000201000 0x000185 0x000185 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000202000 0x0000000000202000 0x001170 0x002005 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x003010 0x0000000000203010 0x0000000000203010 0x000150 0x000150 RW  0x8
  GNU_RELRO      0x003000 0x0000000000203000 0x0000000000203000 0x000170 0x001000 R   0x1
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000440 0x0000000000200440 0x0000000000200440 0x000034 0x000034 R   0x1
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0
  NOTE           0x00028c 0x000000000020028c 0x000000000020028c 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x4

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .rodata .dynsym .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .gnu.hash .hash .dynstr .rela.dyn .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   03     .text .init .fini
   04     .data .tm_clone_table .fini_array .init_array .dynamic .got .bss
   05     .dynamic
   06     .fini_array .init_array .dynamic .got
   07     .eh_frame_hdr
   08
   09     .note.ABI-tag
```

Not to be left behind, the newer BFD-ld (my version is 2.31.1) also makes `ELF` header and `.rodata` read-only, but fails to merge two `R`-only segments into one, resulting in 4 loadable segments:

```
$ echo "int foo; int main() { return 0;}"  | clang -xc - -o a.out-bfd -fuse-ld=bfd
$ readelf -Wl a.out-bfd

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x401020
There are 11 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040 0x000268 0x000268 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x0002a8 0x00000000004002a8 0x00000000004002a8 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x0003f8 0x0003f8 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000 0x00018d 0x00018d R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000402000 0x0000000000402000 0x000110 0x000110 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002e40 0x0000000000403e40 0x0000000000403e40 0x0001e8 0x0001f0 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x002e50 0x0000000000403e50 0x0000000000403e50 0x0001a0 0x0001a0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x0002c4 0x00000000004002c4 0x00000000004002c4 0x000020 0x000020 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x002004 0x0000000000402004 0x0000000000402004 0x000034 0x000034 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x002e40 0x0000000000403e40 0x0000000000403e40 0x0001c0 0x0001c0 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .hash .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn
   03     .init .text .fini
   04     .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   05     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
   06     .dynamic
   07     .note.ABI-tag
   08     .eh_frame_hdr
   09
   10     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

Finally, some of these choices are affected by the `--(no)rosegment` (or `-Wl,z,noseparate-code` for BFD `ld`) linker option.

Comment: For modern binutils(bfd) (v2.31.1+), use `-Wl,-z,noseparate-code` to reduce the number of LOAD-able segments back to 2. xref: https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/commit/f6aec96dce1ddbd8961a3aa8a2925db2021719bb