# ELF Program Headers and Virtual Address

Tags: c, executable, elf, dynamic-linking, readelf

I'm understanding ELF and its program headers. When I read an ELF using `readelf` with file type as DYN. I see virtual address  value in Program Headers is actually from kernel Virtual address space.

```
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x1060
There are 13 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000002d8 0x00000000000002d8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000600 0x0000000000000600  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000
                 0x00000000000001f5 0x00000000000001f5  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000
                 0x0000000000000168 0x0000000000000168  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002db8 0x0000000000003db8 0x0000000000003db8
                 0x0000000000000258 0x0000000000000260  RW     0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000002dc8 0x0000000000003dc8 0x0000000000003dc8
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338
                 0x0000000000000020 0x0000000000000020  R      0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000358 0x0000000000000358 0x0000000000000358
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000000338
                 0x0000000000000020 0x0000000000000020  R      0x8
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000002018 0x0000000000002018 0x0000000000002018
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000002db8 0x0000000000003db8 0x0000000000003db8
                 0x0000000000000248 0x0000000000000248  R      0x1
```

I'm able to deduce the actual VirtAddr at the time of loading the binary should be = Base Address + VirtAddr. But I'm not able to find out how loader calculates the Base Address Value?

Also, I know .text and .data are two PT_LOAD segments for loading the binary. But I see 4 PT_LOAD program headers in my example. What are two PT_LOAD program headers used for?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/chapter6-83432/index.html

Comment: I actually got the idea of base address from this page only. It says "Executable and shared object files have a base address, which is the lowest virtual address associated with the memory image of the program's object file. One use of the base address is to relocate the memory image of the program during dynamic linking."
But I still don't get how to find that lowest virtual address ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see virtual address value in Program Headers is actually from kernel Virtual address space.

No, you *do not* see that. None of the addresses in your output have anything to do with the kernel.

What you are looking at is a [Position Independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables), which can be loaded *anywhere* in memory.

> I'm not able to find out how loader calculates the Base Address Value?

The loader doesn't load the main executable (the kernel does), and doesn't decide the load address.

Given that the file type is `ET_DYN`, the kernel performs an equivalent of
`mmap(0, ...)` (without `MAP_FIXED` flag), and selects a suitable virtual address, which is then communicated to the loader in the `aux` vector.

> But I see 4 PT_LOAD program headers in my example. What are two PT_LOAD program headers used for?

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57841768/50617) answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a program with a set base address. Instead it is a position-independent executable that can be linked to *any* address in the memory, thus enabling address space layout randomization i.e. ALSR.

It differs from an ordinary shared library by just that it has the program interpreter set, normally shared libraries do not have one...

The lowest virtual memory address here is exactly the `0x0000000000000040`, which corresponds to file offset `0x0000000000000040`.