# .text segment bigger than .text section in executable. Why?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, elf

I have the following 'uppercaser.asm' assembly program in NASM which converts all lowercase letters input from user into uppercase:

```
section .bss
    Buff resb 1

section .data

section .text
        global _start

_start:
        nop            ; This no-op keeps the debugger happy

Read:   mov eax,3      ; Specify sys_read call
        mov ebx,0      ; Specify File Descriptor 0: Standard Input
        mov ecx,Buff   ; Pass offset of the buffer to read to
        mov edx,1      ; Tell sys_read to read one char from stdin
        int 80h        ; Call sys_read

        cmp eax,0       ; Look at sys_read's return value in EAX
        je Exit         ; Jump If Equal to 0 (0 means EOF) to Exit
                        ; or fall through to test for lowercase
        cmp byte [Buff],61h  ; Test input char against lowercase 'a'
        jb Write        ; If below 'a' in ASCII chart, not lowercase
        cmp byte [Buff],7Ah  ; Test input char against lowercase 'z'
        ja Write        ; If above 'z' in ASCII chart, not lowercase
                        ; At this point, we have a lowercase character
        sub byte [Buff],20h  ; Subtract 20h from lowercase to give uppercase...
                        ; ...and then write out the char to stdout
Write:  mov eax,4       ; Specify sys_write call
        mov ebx,1       ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard output
        mov ecx,Buff    ; Pass address of the character to write
        mov edx,1       ; Pass number of chars to write
        int 80h         ; Call sys_write...
        jmp Read        ; ...then go to the beginning to get another character

Exit:   mov eax,1       ; Code for Exit Syscall
        mov ebx,0       ; Return a code of zero to Linux
        int 80H         ; Make kernel call to exit program
```

The program is then assembled with the `-g -F stabs` option for the debugger and linked for 32-bit executables in ubuntu 18.04.

Running `readelf --segments uppercaser` for the segments and `readelf -S uppercaser` for the sections I see a difference in size of text segment and text section.

`readelf --segments uppercaser`

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x8048080
There are 2 program headers, starting at offset 52

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x000db 0x000db R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000dc 0x080490dc 0x080490dc 0x00000 0x00004 RW  0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text
   01     .bss
```

`readelf -S uppercaser`

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        08048080 000080 00005b 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 2] .bss              NOBITS          080490dc 0000dc 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 3] .stab             PROGBITS        00000000 0000dc 000120 0c      4   0  4
  [ 4] .stabstr          STRTAB          00000000 0001fc 000011 00      0   0  1
  [ 5] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 00020d 00001f 00      0   0  1
  [ 6] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00022c 00003e 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 0003d4 0000f0 10      8  11  4
  [ 8] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0004c4 000045 00      0   0  1
```

In the sections description one can see that the size of .text section is `5Bh`=91 bytes (the same number one is getting with the `size` command) whereas in the segments description we see that the size is `0x000DB`, a difference of 128 bytes. Why is that?

From the elf man pages for the Elf32_Phdr (program header) structure:

> p_filesz
> This member holds the number of bytes in the file image of
> the segment.  It may be zero.
>
> p_memsz
> This member holds the number of bytes in the memory image
> of the segment.  It may be zero.

Is the difference somehow related to the .bss section?

Answer (score 5):

Notice that the first program segment at file address 0 starts at virtual address `0x08048000`, not at VA `0x08048080` which corresponds with the **.text** section.

In fact the segment displayed by readelf as `00 .text` covers ELF file header (52 bytes), alignment, two program headers (2*32 bytes) and the netto contents of **.text** section, alltogether mapped from file address 0 to VA `0x08048000`.

Comment: Looks like an old version of `ld` (in the OP's Ubuntu 18.04) made this executable; newer `ld` will page-align sections so data such as ELF headers doesn't get mapped into executable pages when it doesn't need to be.  (So those bytes can't be ROP / Spectre gadgets.)  [Minimal executable size now 10x larger after linking than 2 years ago, for tiny programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65037919) / [Why an ELF executable could have 4 LOAD segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57841768)