# Finding all executable code regions in a process

Tags: c, linux, process, elf, virtual-memory

I'm writing a tool for program analysis. I want to find all code regions (i.e. regions with machine instructions) inside the program. I also want to consider dynamically linked code. This far, I have a main process that `fork`s and attaches as a tracer to a sub-process. I read from the `procfs` `/proc/<pid>/maps` to find all executable m-mapped regions (and redo it every time a `mmap` syscall is performed to support dynamic linking), but then I am stuck. I believe all virtual-memory regions that are marked executable in the vm-map are in `ELF` format.

I have tried looking at all section headers with executable permissions in-memory, but sometimes their offset in the `ELF` is outside the mapped space, and as such not inside the executable. I believe I might need to look at the program headers, but I can't get it right.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried looking at all section headers

Section headers are not required to be present in the binary *at all* (they are only used during the stack linking), and are *certainly* not required to be present in memory.

> I believe I might need to look at the program headers, but I can't get it right.

Looking at program headers should give you the segments, yes. But executable segments [may contain read-only data and many other things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57841768/50617), so they will give you a superset of all static "code regions".

In addition, new "code regions" could be created without any associated ELF files (think `mmap` + just-in-time compilation / code generation).

It's unclear *why* you want to find all code regions in the first place (see http://xyproblem.info). Usually binary analysis tools discover them by tracing basic blocks (i.e. by intercepting all control transfer instructions).

Comment: Yeah I get that. As said, I also watch for mmap calls to potentially handle code generation. The task at hand is to find and mark all branching instructions for a given program (and their loaded libraries). I am aware I could do it by tracing, but thought this would be more interesting. So if i get you right; the only way to find ALL code (including generated code) is by tracing the program (potentially from the entrypoint)?

Comment: @Olle I wouldn't say it's the _only_ way. You could in theory statically trace all reachable code by analyzing basic blocks, starting from `_start`. There is existing literature suggesting people have done this. But AFAIU this is infeasibly slow for non-toy binaries.