# `p_offset` in ELF binary

Tags: elf, abi, systems-programming, readelf

I'm trying to learn the ELF format and am implementing an ELF parser. So far, I've implemented the ELF header parser, and I'm working on parsing segments, especially the `.text` segment. I'm stuck here because of the following reasons:

1. When I build a go binary, the program header with `LOAD` type with readable and executable flags (which to my understanding points to the `.text` segment has a p_offset of 0). It must mean that the entire file is readable and executable (as the `p_filesz` is almost the same size as that of the binary.)
2. When I compile a C or Rust program, the problem is not there and the `p_offset` field is properly set with a non-zero value.
3. I don't want to use the section information to parse the `.text` segment from the go binary as it works with all the sections information stripped, so I must be missing something.

In short, How do I find the `.text` segment in a ELF binary with `p_offset` value 0 in a loadable program header with readable and executable flags.

Also, here is the abridged `readelf` dump of the go binary that I'm working with:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x0000000000000150 0x0000000000000150  R      0x1000
  NOTE           0x0000000000000f9c 0x0000000000400f9c 0x0000000000400f9c
                 0x0000000000000064 0x0000000000000064  R      0x4
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x000000000007adfa 0x000000000007adfa  R E    0x1000
```

Thanks!

I've tried reading the System V ELF specification, the x86-64 supplement, tried looking for articles on this topic and asked help from ChatGPT and Bard.

Answer (score 1):

> In short, How do I find the .text segment in a ELF binary with p_offset value 0 in a loadable program header with readable and executable flags.

There is *not* a `.text` segment -- it simply doesn't exist (`.text` section does, but you are not interested in it).

Instead, *multiple* sections are grouped together, and are "covered" by a single `LOAD` segment.

> When I build a go binary, the program header with `LOAD` type with readable and executable flags (which to my understanding points to the `.text` segment has a `p_offset` of 0). It must mean that the entire file is readable and executable (as the `p_filesz` is almost the same size as that of the binary.)

Yes, it means exactly that, and there is *nothing wrong* with that. The linker chose to put everything into one segment (you can see section to segment mapping in `readelf -Wl a.out` output).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57841768/50617).