# yasm movsx, movsxd invalid size for operand 2

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, yasm

I am trying to assemble the code below using yasm. I have put 'here' comments where yasm reports the error "error: invalid size for operand 2". Why is this error happening ?

```
segment .data
    a db 25
    b dw 0xffff
    c dd 3456
    d dq -14

segment .bss
    res resq 1

segment .text
    global _start

_start:
    movsx rax, [a] ; here
    movsx rbx, [b] ; here 
    movsxd rcx, [c] ; here
    mov rdx, [d]
    add rcx, rdx
    add rbx, rcx
    add rax, rbx
    mov [res], rax
    ret
```

Comment: You need to specify size, e.g. `movsx rax, byte [a]`

Comment: well you solved my problem, you should post this as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most instructions, the width of the register operand implies the width of the memory operand, because both operands have to be the same size.  e.g. `mov rdx, [d]` implies `mov rdx, qword [d]` because you used a 64-bit register.

But the same [`movsx`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html) / [`movzx`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVZX.html) mnemonics are used for the byte-source and word-source opcodes, so it's ambiguous unless the source is a register (like `movzx eax, cl`).  Another example is `crc32 r32, r/m8` vs. `r/m16` vs. `r/m32`.  (Unlike movsx/zx, its source size can be as wide as the operand-size.)

**`movsx` / `movzx` with a memory source always need the width of the memory operand specified explicitly.**

The `movsxd` mnemonic is supposed to imply a 32-bit source size.  `movsxd rcx, [c]` assembles with NASM, but apparently not with YASM.  YASM requires you to write `dword`, even though it doesn't accept `byte`, `word`, or `qword` there, and it doesn't accept `movsx  rcx, dword [c]` either (i.e. it requires the `movsxd` mnemonic for 32-bit source operands).

In NASM, `movsx  rcx, dword [c]` assembles to `movsxd`, but `movsxd   rcx, word [c]` is still rejected.  i.e. in NASM, plain `movsx` is fully flexible, but `movsxd` is still rigid.  I'd still recommend using `dword` to make the width of the load explicit, for the benefit of humans.

```
movsx    rax,  byte [a]
movsx    rbx,  word [b]
movsxd   rcx, dword [c]
```

Note that the "operand size" of the instruction (as determined by the operand-size prefix to make it 16-bit, or REX.W=1 to make it 64-bit) is the destination width for `movsx` / `movzx`.  Different source sizes use different opcodes.

---

In case it's not obvious, there's no `movzxd` because [32-bit `mov` already zero-extends to 64-bit implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register).  `movsxd  eax, ecx` is encodeable, but not recommended (use `mov` instead).

In AT&T syntax, you need to explicitly specify both the source and destination width in the mnemonic, like `movsbq (%rsi), %rax`.  GAS won't let you write `movsb (%rsi), %eax` to infer a destination width (operand-size) because `movsb`/`movsw`/etc are the mnemonics for [string-move instructions](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq) with implicit (%rsi), (%rdi) operands.

Fun fact: GAS and clang do allow it for things like `movzb (%rsi), %eax` as `movzbl`, but GAS only has extra logic to allow disambiguation (not just inferring size) based on operands when it's necessary, like `movsd (%rsi), %xmm0` vs. `movsd`.  (Clang12.0.1 actually does accept `movsb (%rcx), %eax` as `movsbl`, but GAS 2.36.1 doesn't, so for portability it's best to be explicit with sign-extension, and not a bad idea for zero-extension too.)

---

Other stuff about your source code:

NASM/YASM allow you to use the `segment` keyword instead of `section`, but really you're giving ELF section names, not executable segment names.  Also, you can put read-only data in `section .rodata` (which is linked as part of the text segment).  [What's the difference of section and segment in ELF file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361248/whats-the-difference-of-section-and-segment-in-elf-file-format).

You can't `ret` from `_start`.  It's not a function, it's your ELF entry point.  The first thing on the stack is `argc`, not a valid return address.  Use this to exit cleanly:

```
xor    edi,edi
mov    eax, 231
syscall            ; sys_exit_group(0)
```

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to more useful guides (and debugging tips at the bottom).

Comment: Are these AT&T examples `movsb`, `movsw`, and  `movsb (%rsi), %rax` still about sign-extending? What does AT&T use for the (anonymous) string primitives MoveStringByte (`movsb`) and MoveStringWord (`movsw`)?

Comment: @SepRoland: Good point.  I thought the operands would disambiguate like they do for `movsd` vs. `movsd (%rdi), %xmm0`.  But no. Current GAS accepts `movzb %al, %ecx` (inferring the `l` destination size), but errors on `movsb %al, %ecx`.  If you try with `movsb (%rdi), %ecx`, it warns that it expected `(%rsi)` as the source before erroring on operand-type mismatch (presumably for the register destination); I guess AT&T syntax allows the explicit-operand version.  So yeah, for `movsb`, it matches the string mnemonic and doesn't go back and consider it as sign-extension with implicit dst size.