# YASM: Instruction movsx refuses dword for operand size?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, mov, yasm

An assembly program I'm writing will not compile with the y assembler, citing:

```
error: invalid size for operand 2
```

On the following line:

```
movsx rbx, dword [rsi+4*rcx]    ; Copy double-word and sign extend.
```

However, I can't find any reason why `dword` should not work. I want to move a double-word (4 bytes) at address `rsi+4*rcx` into 8 byte register `rbx`. So there remain 32 bits to be "padded" after copying it into what is effectively `ebx`. If I change the size to `byte`, I get no error. But this is not what I want.

There is a question with a similar title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350568/yasm-movsx-movsxd-invalid-size-for-operand-2). However, the poster had forgotten to include any size operands whatsoever, and the answer to the question did not resolve my problem.

**Edit**: I've added the full program below in case the particular syntax I've copied here is not the culprit.

```
    segment .data

a:
    dd  1
    dd  3
    dd  0
    dd  1
    dd  7
    dd  9
    dd  5
    dd  2
b:
    dd  8
    dd  3
    dd  3
    dd  9
    dd  6
    dd  4
    dd  1
    dd  1

p   dq  0

    segment .text
    global main

main:
    xor rax, rax                    ; Set sum to 0.
    xor rcx, rcx                    ; Set counter to 0.
    lea rsi, [a]                    ; Set source 1.
    lea rdi, [b]                    ; Set source 2.

dot:
    movsx rbx, dword [rsi+4*rcx]    ; Copy in double-word.
    movsx rdx, dword [rdi+4*rcx]    ; Copy in other double-word.        
    imul rbx, rdx                   ; Multiply the two double-words.
    add rax, rbx                    ; Sum product so far.
    inc rcx
    cmp rcx, 8
    jz done
    jmp dot

done:
    mov [p], rax

    xor rax, rax
    ret
```

Comment: Your program uses `movzx`, not `movsx`. Typo? There is no `movzx r64, r/m32` instruction because you just write `mov r32, r/m32` and let the built-in zero-extension do the work.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes I corrected it. I was experimenting when I copied it in. The error still holds for condition stated in the title.

Comment: @RaymondChen His suggestion yields the same errors.

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate as the duplicate has a better answer.

Comment: @fuz The question you marked it as a duplicate of was one I visited and mentioned inside my post. But the answer did not solve my problem.

Comment: @Micrified The answer does specifically say: “YASM requires you to write dword, even though it doesn't accept byte, word, or qword there, and it doesn't accept movsx  rcx, dword [c] either (i.e. it requires the movsxd mnemonic for 32-bit source operands).”  This is the exact same advice I gave in my answer, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assembler calls the desired instruction `movsxd` for some reason:

```
movsxd rbx, dword [rsi+4*rcx]
```

This should work.

Comment: Sadly I am still given: `invalid size for operand 2` as feedback when this suggestion was implemented.

Comment: this is weird.  Have you also tried `movsxd rbx, [dword rsi+4*rcx]` for good measure?

Comment: The second suggestion did not work either. Here is a quick [demonstration](https://youtu.be/LflSc6wY0nw) of what happens when I compile, so that it is clear I am not making a mistake elsewhere.

Comment: @Micrified Oh, the `dword` keyword goes before the brackets, sorry.  Can you try `movsxd rbx, dword [rsi+4*rcx]` please?  And I always appreciate ACME users.

Comment: The program compiles now, and works correctly as well. If you update your answer I will gladly accept it! I'm glad you like Acme. I find it does a lot of things right and works well with my small programs. :>

Comment: "for some reason" is because that's what AMD named it.  That's a bit of a mystery, instead of just adding a 3rd opcode for `movsx`, but you make it sound like it was YASM's weird decision to name it this way.  YASM simply omitted NASM's `movsx` alias for [`movsxd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd).  Fun fact: the opcode for `movsxd` is only useful with a REX.W prefix.

Comment: @Micrified: the code in your youtube(!) link (integer dot-product widening from 32 to 64-bit) looks like a use-case for SSE2 `pmuldq`/`paddq` so you can do a pair of integers in parallel.  But to feed it you'll need to shuffle your inputs, e.g. load with SSE4.1 `pmovzxdq xmm0, qword [rsi + 4*rcx]`, or do 128-bit loads and `punpckldq` / `hdq` against a zeroed register.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think those instructions are a bit beyond my capabilities at the moment. I am generally just completing suggested exercises in a textbook to get familiar and have only cursory assembly knowledge. However, I'm always interested in knowing of faster ways to do things! If you post this as an answer with a bit more context, I'll give it a vote (I already accepted an answer by now). Thank you for your input nonetheless!

Comment: @Micrified: Once you learn anything about SIMD, you should be able to understand what I'm talking about.  See also https://agner.org/optimize/, his optimization guide has a chapter on SIMD.  Hopefully compilers can auto-vectorize the way I suggested from a C loop, too, so you could get an example that way.