# No memory source operand for crc32 in Delphi 11?

Tags: delphi, assembly, x86-64, crc32

The *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual* Clearly shows the addressing modes for `crc32` instruction in 64-bit environment:

```
...
CRC32 r64, r/m64
...
```

However, in *Delphi 11* the following gets `[dcc64 Error]: E2116 Invalid combination of opcode and operands` in 64-bit Windows environment:

```
procedure crc;
asm
  crc32 r11, [r10]
end;
```

Is here something I regrettably miss or this is just another stupid Delphi 11 bug?!

Comment: Set the type for the second operand, `crc32 r11, qword ptr [r10]`

Comment: So you say that if there might be ambiguities in the byte size of the indirectly addressed operand mode the *Delphi* automaticallly signals a compile error? If so why the `mov [r10], 0` is still accepted, where 0 can be byte up to qword?  Doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: For CRC32 there is also `CRC32 reg64, reg/mem8` which means without setting the type of the memory reference there is some ambiguity as to which type is meant. For example `crc32 r11, byte ptr [r10]` is also valid.  The `mov` instruction does not have this ambiguity.

Comment: It indeed has this ambiguity! `mov byte ptr [r10], 0` is equally valid as `mov qword ptr [r10], 0`. The ambiguity for `mov` is even much more dangerorus than the one from `crc32`, as a `mov` with incorrect operand size can easily overwrite data in an unwanted way.

Comment: A good assembler *doesn't* accept `mov [r10], 0`, because it *is* ambiguous between byte, word, dword, and qword, @Brian.  NASM rejects it, with helpful error about ambiguous operand-size.  A bad assembler will just pick some default which might or might not be what you had in mind!  (GAS used to silently accept ambiguous operand-sizes for instructions other than `mov`, e.g. for `add`, defaulting to dword.  That made zero sense; now it at least warns, unfortunately not erroring.)  A generic error message like "invalid combination" is better than a silent default, but not very helpful.

Comment: @PeterCordes In this case it does mean that the Embarcadero Delphi complier is **NOT** a good assembler. Moreover, is an inconsistent one as even tie ambiguity tolerance is not the same across different instructions. Hence, the negative vote for my question is at least weird, I definitely don't deserve it.

Comment: Want to set @Brian's answer as the good one. How I can do it as ist's just a comment?

Comment: Not my vote, agreed this doesn't really deserve a downvote.  And yes, unfortunately not all real-world assemblers are good. :/  NASM is one of the best, having had decades of open-source development with people improving and specializing its error messages for different corner cases.  As well as carefully-chosen behaviour for corner cases.  Its developers are real asm experts, not just writing an assembler as part of a compiler.

Comment: You can write up an answer yourself, putting stuff from comments into your own words.  (At least the correct stuff.)  You can't "accept" a comment.  It's not really a duplicate, unless there's one that uses `movzx` as an example, which similarly can have different memory source sizes for a fixed register destination width.

Comment: [yasm movsx, movsxd invalid size for operand 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47350568) is basically the same question but for YASM/NASM syntax with movsx.  I added a mention of `crc32` as another example of memory size not being implied by a register destination.  Once you realize the problem is ambiguity, using `qword ptr` instead of YASM `qword` should be obvious, so I don't think anyone need to take the time to write up an answer to this question, it's sufficiently solved by a duplicate.