# Segmentation fault with a variable in SECTION .DATA

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I am trying to learn nasm. I want to make a program that prints "Hello, world." n times (in this case 10). I am trying to save the loop register value in a constant so that it is not changed when the body of the loop is executed. When I try to do this I receive a segmentation fault error. I am not sure why this is happening.

My code:

```
SECTION .DATA
    print_str:          db 'Hello, world.', 10
    print_str_len:      equ $-print_str

    limit:              equ 10
    step:               dw 1

SECTION .TEXT
    GLOBAL _start 

_start:
    mov eax, 4              ; 'write' system call = 4
    mov ebx, 1              ; file descriptor 1 = STDOUT
    mov ecx, print_str      ; string to write
    mov edx, print_str_len  ; length of string to write
    int 80h                 ; call the kernel

    mov eax, [step]         ; moves the step value to eax
    inc eax                 ; Increment
    mov [step], eax         ; moves the eax value to step
    cmp eax, limit          ; Compare sil to the limit
    jle _start              ; Loop while less or equal

exit:
    mov eax, 1              ; 'exit' system call
    mov ebx, 0              ; exit with error code 0
    int 80h                 ; call the kernel
```

The result:

```
Hello, world.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The cmd:

```
nasm -f elf64 file.asm -o file.o
ld file.o -o file
./file
```

Comment: Which instruction is crashing?

Comment: You define step as a word (16-bits) but you move 32-bits of data to it with `mov [step], eax` . As well the section names `.DATA` and `.TEXT` should be lower case, not upper case

Comment: I can't say with complete confidence but if I change ```mov [step], eax``` (comment it out or something) the code will run without crashing. It just iterates through the loop once.

Comment: Can you move 16-bits instead of a 32-bit mov?

Comment: You should use `dd` not `dw`.

Comment: I changed the step definition to dd but received the same result.

Comment: Did you fix the section names?

Comment: What is incorrect about them?

Comment: See my comment above. It mentions the names need to be lower case. `.text` and `.data` are special, but `.DATA` and `.TEXT` are not.

Comment: Also see [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730/547981) for later reference.

Comment: O i see. I have one last (slightly unrelated) question. What does the ", 10" after the string variable do in masm? I saw that on an example so I am not sure what its purpose is. That fixed the problem. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: 10 is a line feed character to go to the next line. In Unix/Linux a line feed is the same as `\n` in _C_

Comment: Ok. Everything works now. Thanks again.

Comment: in x86 assembly you can also do `inc dword [step]` and `cmp dword [step],limit`, (as limit in the second case is just numeric immediate constant, and `cmp r/m32, imm32` exists). (but you must specify size of operand then, as assembler can't tell from `inc [step]` if you want to increment one, two or four (or eight in 64b mode) bytes, such line is ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

`section .DATA` is the direct cause of the crash.  Lower-case `section .data` is special, and linked as a read-write (private) mapping of the executable.  Section names are case-sensitive.

**Upper-case `.DATA` is not special for nasm or the linker, and it ends up as part of the [text segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361248/whats-the-difference-of-section-and-segment-in-elf-file-format) mapped read+exec without write permission.**

Upper-case `.TEXT` is also weird: by default `objdump -drwC -Mintel` only disassembles the `.text` section (to avoid disassembling data as if it were code), so it shows empty output for your executable.

[On newer systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72523133/trivial-assembler-program-segfaults), the default for a section name NASM doesn't recognize doesn't include exec permission, so code in `.TEXT` will segfault.  Same as [Assembly section .code and .text behave differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67084048/assembly-section-code-and-text-behave-differently/67085510#67085510)

---

After starting the program under GDB (`gdb ./foo`, `starti`), I looked at the process's memory map from another shell.

```
$ cat /proc/11343/maps
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:31 110651257                          /tmp/foo
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
```

As you can see, other than the special VDSO mappings and the stack, there's only the one file-backed mapping, and it has read+exec permission only.

Single-stepping inside GDB, the `mov    eax,DWORD PTR ds:0x400086` load succeeds, but **the `mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x400086,eax` store faults**.  (See the bottom of the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for GDB asm tips.)

**From `readelf -a foo`**, we can see the ELF program headers that tell the OS's program loader how to map it into memory:

```
$ readelf -a foo   # broken version
  ...
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000000bf 0x00000000000000bf  R      0x200000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .DATA .TEXT
```

Notice how both `.DATA` and `.TEXT` are in the same segment.  This is what you'd want for `section .rodata` (a standard section name where you should put read-only constant data like your string), but it won't work for mutable global variables.

**After fixing your asm to use `section .data` and `.text`, readelf shows us:**

```
$ readelf -a foo    # fixed version
  ...
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000000e7 0x00000000000000e7  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x00000000000000e8 0x00000000006000e8 0x00000000006000e8
                 0x0000000000000010 0x0000000000000010  RW     0x200000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .text 
   01     .data
```

Notice how segment 00 is R + E without W, and the `.text` section is in there.  Segment 01 is RW (read + write) without exec, and the `.data` section is there.

The `LOAD` tag means they're mapped into the process's virtual address space.  Some section (like debug info) aren't, and are just metadata for other tools.  But NASM flags unknown section names as progbits, i.e. loaded, which is why it was able to link and have the load not segfault.

---

**After fixing it to use `section .data`, your program runs without segfaulting**.

The loop runs for one iteration, because the 2 bytes following `step: dw 1` are not zero.  After the dword load, `RAX = 0x2c0001` on my system.  (`cmp` between 0x002c0002 and `0xa` makes the LE condition false because it's not less or equal.)

`dw` means "data word" or "define word".  **Use `dd` for a data dword**.

---

BTW, **there's no need to keep your loop counter in memory**.  You're not using RDI, RSI, RBP, or R8..R15 for anything so you could just keep it in a register.  Like `mov edi, limit` before the loop, and `dec edi / jnz` at the bottom.

But actually you should use the 64-bit `syscall` ABI if you want to build 64-bit code, not the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI. [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  Or build 32-bit executables if you're following a guide or tutorial written for that.

Anyway, in that case you'd be able to use `ebx` as your loop counter, because the syscall ABI uses different args for registers.