# Assembly section .code and .text behave differently

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, elf

I'm new to assembly and from what I learned the `.code` is same with `.text`, but the code below will crash using the `.code`.

```
segment .data
    msg db "hello, world", 0xa
    len equ $ - msg

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov edx, len
    mov ecx, msg

    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

```
nasm -f elf64 -o hello.o hello.s 
ld -s -o hello hello.o
hello, world

sed -i s/.text/.code/ ./hello.s
nasm -f elf64 -o hello.o hello.s 
ld -s -o hello hello.o
./stack.sh: line 8:  4621 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./hello
```

Actually, I don't think it's different. Why this happen ?

Comment: You learned it wrong. In nasm `.code` is not recognized. See the [manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.2). Notice in particular that unrecognized sections are `noexec`.

Comment: `section .text` is the NASM / Linux *equivalent* of Windows MASM `.code`, i.e. where you put your instructions.  `section .code` doesn't actually do what you want in NASM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux with the standard toolchain (GNU Binutils `ld`), `.text` is a "special" section name that gets special treatment (exec permission by default), but `.code` isn't.  (Other special sections include `.data` (writeable) and `.bss` (writable nobits), and all with a default alignment > 1.)

`section .text` is the NASM ELF/Linux equivalent of Windows MASM `.code` directive, but that does *not* mean that Linux tools recognize a `.code` directive or section name<sup>1</sup>.

**`section .code` is no different from `section xyz123`; it just uses the defaults which are `noexec` `nowrite`.**  See the `other` entry at the bottom of [the table in the NASM docs](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.2).

Use `readelf -a hello` to see the section (linking) and segment (program-loader) attributes, with a distinct lack of an `X` anywhere.

Footnote 1: In fact, I think Windows executables still use the actual section name `.text`.  At least GNU `objdump -d` still says the code is in the `.text` section.
So the MASM `.code` directive is a shortcut for switching to the `.text` section.

---

Fun fact: this does happen to run correctly "by accident" if you build it as 32-bit code (which you should [because it's using only 32-bit `int 0x80` system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)), like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316059/assembly-code-do-not-recognise-and-data) that used `section .code` when incorrectly porting from 16-bit MASM code to Linux NASM.
Or if you'd run your 64-bit code on an older kernel.

The reason is that without explicitly specifying a `PT_GNU_STACK` note, the kernel uses backwards-compat assumptions for 32-bit executables and uses `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC` which affects every single page: [Linux default behavior of executable .data section changed between 5.4 and 5.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833715/linux-default-behavior-of-executable-data-section-changed-between-5-4-and-5-9).  Older kernels do this even for 64-bit executables, newer kernels only make the stack itself executable in this case.

Adding `section .note.GNU-stack noalloc noexec nowrite progbits` to your source makes it segfault as it should, even when build into a 32-bit executable.  (`nasm -felf32` / `ld -melf_i386 -o foo foo.o`).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863200/why-data-and-stack-segments-are-executable).

See also [Unexpected exec permission from mmap when assembly files included in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260465/unexpected-exec-permission-from-mmap-when-assembly-files-included-in-the-project) about the old situation.

Comment: _Side note:_ Peter, if you haven't already seen this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67098983/why-does-a-loop-transitioning-from-having-its-uops-fed-by-the-uop-cache-to-lsd-c you're gonna love it. For content/questions. And, OP's question is as detailed as one of your answers. And, the formatting style looks very much like one of your answers.