# Why does a loop transitioning from having its uops fed by the Uop Cache to LSD cause a spike in branch-misses?

Tags: x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization, branch-prediction, micro-architecture

All benchmarks are run on either
**[Icelake](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196597/intel-core-i7-1065g7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html)**
or **[Whiskey Lake](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/149091/intel-core-i7-8565u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html)** (In Skylake Family).

### Summary

I am seeing a strange phenomina where it appears that when a loop
transitions from running out of the **Uop Cache** to running out of
the **LSD (Loop Stream Detector)** there is a spike in **Branch
Misses** that can cause severe performance hits. I tested on both
Icelake and Whiskey Lake by benchmarking a nested loop with the outer loop
having a sufficiently large body s.t the entire thing did not fit in
the **LSD** itself, but with an inner loop small enough to fit in the
**LSD**.

Basically once the inner loop reaches some iteration count decoding
seems to switch for **idq.dsb_uops (Uop Cache)** to **lsd.uops (LSD)**
and at that point there is a large increase in **branch-misses**
(without a corresponding jump in **branches**) causing a severe
performance drop. **Note: This only seems to occur for nested
loops. [Travis Down's Loop
Test](https://github.com/travisdowns/x86-loop-test) for example will
not show any meaningful variation in branch misses**. AFAICT this has
something to do with when a loop transitions from running out of the
**Uop Cache** to running out of the **LSD**.

### Questions

1. What is happening when the loop transitions from running out of the
   **Uop Cache** to running out of the **LSD** that causes this spike in
   **Branch Misses**?
2. Is there a way to avoid this?

### Benchmark

This is the minimum reproducible example I could come up with:

Note: If the `.p2align` statements are removed both loops will fit in
the LSD and there will not be a transitions.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BENCH_ATTR __attribute__((noinline, noclone, aligned(4096)))

static const uint64_t outer_N = (1UL << 24);


static void BENCH_ATTR
bench(uint64_t inner_N) {
    uint64_t inner_loop_cnt, outer_loop_cnt;
    asm volatile(
        ".p2align 12\n"
        "movl   %k[outer_N], %k[outer_loop_cnt]\n"
        ".p2align   6\n"
        "1:\n"
        "movl   %k[inner_N], %k[inner_loop_cnt]\n"
        // Extra align surrounding inner loop so that the entire thing
        // doesn't execute out of LSD.
        ".p2align   10\n"
        "2:\n"
        "decl   %k[inner_loop_cnt]\n"
        "jnz    2b\n"
        ".p2align   10\n"
        "decl   %k[outer_loop_cnt]\n"
        "jnz    1b\n"
        : [ inner_loop_cnt ] "=&r"(inner_loop_cnt),
          [ outer_loop_cnt ] "=&r"(outer_loop_cnt)
        : [ inner_N ] "ri"(inner_N), [ outer_N ] "i"(outer_N)
        :);
}
int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    assert(argc > 1);
    uint64_t inner_N = atoi(argv[1]);
    bench(inner_N);
}
```

**Compile**: `gcc -O3 -march=native -mtune=native <filename>.c -o <filename>`

**Run Icelake**: `sudo perf stat -C 0 --all-user -e cycles -e branches -e branch-misses -x, -e idq.ms_uops -e idq.dsb_uops -e lsd.uops taskset -c 0 ./<filename> <N inner loop iterations>`

**Run Whiskey Lake**: `sudo perf stat -C 0 -e cycles -e branches -e branch-misses -x, -e idq.ms_uops -e idq.dsb_uops -e lsd.uops taskset -c 0 ./<filename> <N inner loop iterations>`

### Graphs

Edit: x label is N iterations of inner loop.

Below is a graph of **Branch Misses**, **Branches**, and **LSD Uops**.

Generally you can see that 1) there is no corresponding jump in **Branches**. 2) that the number of added **Branch Misses** stabilizes at a constant. And 3) That there is a strong relationship between the **Branch Misses** and **LSD Uops**.

**Icelake Graph**:

[image: icl-branch]

**Whiskey Lake Graph**:

[image: skl-branch]

Below is a graph of **Branch Misses**, **Cycles**, and **LSD Uops**
for **Icelake** only as performance is not affected nearly as much on:

[image: icl-cycles]

### Analysis

Hard numbers below.

For **Icelake** starting at `N = 22` and finishing at `N = 27` there
is some fluctuation in the number of uops coming from the **LSD** vs
**Uop Cache** and during that time **Branch Misses** increases by
roughly 3 order of magnitude from *10^4 -> 10^7*. During this period
**Cycles** also increased by a factor of *2*. For all `N > 27`
**Branch Misses** stays at around *1.67 x 10^7* (roughly `outer_loop_N`). For `N = [17, 40]`
**branches** continues to only increase linearly.

The results for **Whiskey Lake** look different in that 1) `N` begins fluctuating at `N = 35` and continues to fluctuate until `N = 49`. And 2) there is less of a
performance impact and more fluctuation in the data. That being said
the increase in **Branch-Misses** corresponding with transitions from
uops being fed by **Uop Cache** to being fed by **LSD** still exists.

### Results

Data is mean result for 25 runs.

**Icelake Results**:

| N | cycles | branches | branch-misses | idq.ms_uops | idq.dsb_uops | lsd.uops |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33893260 | 67129521 | 1590 | 43163 | 115243 | 83908732 |
| 2 | 42540891 | 83908928 | 1762 | 49023 | 142909 | 100690381 |
| 3 | 50725933 | 100686143 | 1782 | 47656 | 142506 | 117440256 |
| 4 | 67533597 | 117461172 | 1655 | 52538 | 186123 | 134158311 |
| 5 | 68022910 | 134238387 | 1711 | 53405 | 204481 | 150954035 |
| 6 | 85543126 | 151018722 | 1924 | 62445 | 141397 | 167633971 |
| 7 | 84847823 | 167799220 | 1935 | 60248 | 160146 | 184563523 |
| 8 | 101532158 | 184570060 | 1709 | 60064 | 361208 | 201100179 |
| 9 | 101864898 | 201347253 | 1773 | 63827 | 459873 | 217780207 |
| 10 | 118024033 | 218124499 | 1698 | 59480 | 177223 | 234834304 |
| 11 | 118644416 | 234908571 | 2201 | 62514 | 422977 | 251503052 |
| 12 | 134627567 | 251678909 | 1679 | 57262 | 133462 | 268435650 |
| 13 | 285607942 | 268456135 | 1770 | 74070 | 285032524 | 315423 |
| 14 | 302717754 | 285233352 | 1731 | 74663 | 302101097 | 15953 |
| 15 | 321627434 | 302010569 | 81796 | 77831 | 319192830 | 1520819 |
| 16 | 337876736 | 318787786 | 71638 | 77056 | 335904260 | 1265766 |
| 17 | 353054773 | 335565563 | 1798 | 79839 | 352434780 | 15879 |
| 18 | 369800279 | 352344970 | 1978 | 79863 | 369229396 | 16790 |
| 19 | 386921048 | 369119438 | 1972 | 84075 | 385984022 | 16115 |
| 20 | 404248461 | 385896655 | 29454 | 85348 | 402790977 | 510176 |
| 21 | 421100725 | 402673872 | 37598 | 83400 | 419537730 | 729397 |
| 22 | 519623794 | 419451095 | 4447767 | 91209 | 431865775 | 97827331 |
| 23 | 702206338 | 436228323 | 12603617 | 109064 | 427880075 | 327661987 |
| 24 | 710626194 | 453005538 | 12316933 | 106929 | 432926173 | 344838509 |
| 25 | 863214037 | 469782765 | 14641887 | 121776 | 428085132 | 614871430 |
| 26 | 761037251 | 486559974 | 13067814 | 113011 | 438093034 | 418124984 |
| 27 | 832686921 | 503337195 | 16381350 | 113953 | 421924080 | 556915419 |
| 28 | 854713119 | 520114412 | 16642396 | 124448 | 420515666 | 598907353 |
| 29 | 869873144 | 536891629 | 16572581 | 119280 | 421188631 | 629696780 |
| 30 | 889642335 | 553668847 | 16717446 | 120116 | 420086570 | 668628871 |
| 31 | 906912275 | 570446064 | 16735759 | 126094 | 419970933 | 702822733 |
| 32 | 923023862 | 587223281 | 16706519 | 132498 | 420332680 | 735003892 |
| 33 | 940308170 | 604000498 | 16744992 | 124365 | 419945191 | 770185745 |
| 34 | 957075000 | 620777716 | 16726856 | 133675 | 420215897 | 802779119 |
| 35 | 974557538 | 637554932 | 16763071 | 134871 | 419764866 | 838012637 |
| 36 | 991110971 | 654332149 | 16772560 | 130903 | 419641144 | 872037131 |
| 37 | 1008489575 | 671109367 | 16757219 | 138788 | 419900997 | 904638287 |
| 38 | 1024971256 | 687886583 | 16772585 | 139782 | 419663863 | 938988917 |
| 39 | 1041404669 | 704669411 | 16776722 | 137681 | 419617131 | 972896126 |
| 40 | 1058594326 | 721441018 | 16773492 | 142959 | 419662133 | 1006109192 |
| 41 | 1075179100 | 738218235 | 16776636 | 141185 | 419601996 | 1039892900 |
| 42 | 1092093726 | 754995452 | 16776233 | 142793 | 419611902 | 1073373451 |
| 43 | 1108706464 | 771773224 | 16776359 | 139500 | 419610885 | 1106976114 |
| 44 | 1125413652 | 788549886 | 16764637 | 143717 | 419889127 | 1139628280 |
| 45 | 1142023614 | 805327103 | 16778640 | 144397 | 419558217 | 1174329696 |
| 46 | 1158833317 | 822104321 | 16765518 | 148045 | 419889914 | 1206833484 |
| 47 | 1175665684 | 838881537 | 16778437 | 148347 | 419562885 | 1241397845 |
| 48 | 1192454164 | 855658755 | 16778865 | 153651 | 419552747 | 1275006511 |
| 49 | 1210199084 | 872436025 | 16778287 | 152468 | 419599314 | 1307945613 |
| 50 | 1226321832 | 889213188 | 16778464 | 155552 | 419572344 | 1341893668 |
| 51 | 1242886388 | 905990406 | 16778745 | 155401 | 419559249 | 1375589883 |
| 52 | 1259559053 | 922767623 | 16778809 | 154847 | 419554082 | 1409206082 |
| 53 | 1276875799 | 939544839 | 16778460 | 162521 | 419576455 | 1442424993 |
| 54 | 1293113199 | 956322057 | 16778931 | 154913 | 419550955 | 1476316161 |
| 55 | 1310449232 | 973099274 | 16778534 | 157364 | 419578102 | 1509485876 |
| 56 | 1327022109 | 989876491 | 16778794 | 162881 | 419562403 | 1543193559 |
| 57 | 1344097516 | 1006653708 | 16778906 | 157486 | 419567545 | 1576414302 |
| 58 | 1362935064 | 1023430928 | 16778959 | 315120 | 419583132 | 1609691339 |
| 59 | 1381567560 | 1040208143 | 16778564 | 179997 | 419661259 | 1640660745 |
| 60 | 1394829416 | 1056985359 | 16778779 | 167613 | 419575969 | 1677034188 |
| 61 | 1411847237 | 1073762626 | 16778071 | 166332 | 419613028 | 1710194702 |
| 62 | 1428918439 | 1090539795 | 16778409 | 168073 | 419610487 | 1743644637 |
| 63 | 1445223241 | 1107317011 | 16778486 | 172446 | 419591254 | 1777573503 |
| 64 | 1461530579 | 1124094228 | 16769606 | 169559 | 419970612 | 1810351736 |

**Whiskey Lake Results**:

| N | cycles | branches | branch-misses | idq.dsb_uops | lsd.uops |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8332553879 | 35005847 | 37925 | 1799462 | 6019 |
| 2 | 8329926329 | 51163346 | 34338 | 1114352 | 5919 |
| 3 | 8357233041 | 67925775 | 32270 | 9241935 | 5555 |
| 4 | 8379609449 | 85364250 | 35667 | 18215077 | 5712 |
| 5 | 8394301337 | 101563554 | 33177 | 26392216 | 2159 |
| 6 | 8409830612 | 118918934 | 35007 | 35318763 | 5295 |
| 7 | 8435794672 | 135162597 | 35592 | 43033739 | 4478 |
| 8 | 8445843118 | 152636271 | 37802 | 52154850 | 5629 |
| 9 | 8459141676 | 168577876 | 30766 | 59245754 | 1543 |
| 10 | 8475484632 | 185354280 | 30825 | 68059212 | 4672 |
| 11 | 8493529857 | 202489273 | 31703 | 77386249 | 5556 |
| 12 | 8509281533 | 218912407 | 32133 | 84390084 | 4399 |
| 13 | 8528605921 | 236303681 | 33056 | 93995496 | 2093 |
| 14 | 8553971099 | 252439989 | 572416 | 99700289 | 2477 |
| 15 | 8558526147 | 269148605 | 29912 | 109772044 | 6121 |
| 16 | 8576658106 | 286414453 | 29839 | 118504526 | 5850 |
| 17 | 8591545887 | 302698593 | 28993 | 126409458 | 4865 |
| 18 | 8611628234 | 319960954 | 32568 | 136298306 | 5066 |
| 19 | 8627289083 | 336312187 | 30094 | 143759724 | 6598 |
| 20 | 8644741581 | 353730396 | 49458 | 152217853 | 9275 |
| 21 | 8685908403 | 369886284 | 1175195 | 161313923 | 7958903 |
| 22 | 8694494654 | 387336207 | 354008 | 169541244 | 2553802 |
| 23 | 8702920906 | 403389097 | 29315 | 176524452 | 12932 |
| 24 | 8711458401 | 420211718 | 31924 | 184984842 | 11574 |
| 25 | 8729941722 | 437299615 | 32472 | 194553843 | 12002 |
| 26 | 8743658904 | 453739403 | 28809 | 202074676 | 13279 |
| 27 | 8763317458 | 470902005 | 32298 | 211321630 | 15377 |
| 28 | 8788189716 | 487432842 | 37105 | 218972477 | 27666 |
| 29 | 8796580152 | 504414945 | 36756 | 228334744 | 79954 |
| 30 | 8821174857 | 520930989 | 39550 | 235849655 | 140461 |
| 31 | 8818857058 | 537611096 | 34142 | 648080 | 79191 |
| 32 | 8855038758 | 555138781 | 37680 | 18414880 | 70489 |
| 33 | 8870680446 | 571194669 | 37541 | 34596108 | 131455 |
| 34 | 8888946679 | 588222521 | 33724 | 52553756 | 80009 |
| 35 | 9256640352 | 604791887 | 16658672 | 132185723 | 41881719 |
| 36 | 9189040776 | 621918353 | 12296238 | 257921026 | 235389707 |
| 37 | 8962737456 | 638241888 | 1086663 | 109613368 | 35222987 |
| 38 | 9005853511 | 655453884 | 2059624 | 131945369 | 73389550 |
| 39 | 9005576553 | 671845678 | 1434478 | 143002441 | 51959363 |
| 40 | 9284680907 | 688991063 | 12776341 | 349762585 | 347998221 |
| 41 | 9049931865 | 705399210 | 1778532 | 174597773 | 72566933 |
| 42 | 9314836359 | 722226758 | 12743442 | 365270833 | 380415682 |
| 43 | 9072200927 | 739449289 | 1344663 | 205181163 | 61284843 |
| 44 | 9346737669 | 755766179 | 12681859 | 383580355 | 409359111 |
| 45 | 9117099955 | 773167996 | 1801713 | 235583664 | 88985013 |
| 46 | 9108062783 | 789247474 | 860680 | 250992592 | 43508069 |
| 47 | 9129892784 | 806871038 | 984804 | 268229102 | 51249366 |
| 48 | 9146468279 | 822765997 | 1018387 | 282312588 | 58278399 |
| 49 | 9476835578 | 840085058 | 13985421 | 241172394 | 809315446 |
| 50 | 9495578885 | 856579327 | 14155046 | 241909464 | 847629148 |
| 51 | 9537115189 | 873483093 | 15057500 | 238735335 | 932663942 |
| 52 | 9556102594 | 890026435 | 15322279 | 238194482 | 982429654 |
| 53 | 9589094741 | 907142375 | 15899251 | 234845868 | 1052080437 |
| 54 | 9609053333 | 923477989 | 16049518 | 233890599 | 1092323040 |
| 55 | 9628950166 | 940997348 | 16172619 | 235383688 | 1131146866 |
| 56 | 9650657175 | 957049360 | 16445697 | 231276680 | 1183699383 |
| 57 | 9666446210 | 973785857 | 16330748 | 233203869 | 1205098118 |
| 58 | 9687274222 | 990692518 | 16523542 | 230842647 | 1254624242 |
| 59 | 9706652879 | 1007946602 | 16576268 | 231502185 | 1288374980 |
| 60 | 9720091630 | 1024044005 | 16547047 | 230966608 | 1321807705 |
| 61 | 9741079017 | 1041285110 | 16635400 | 230873663 | 1362929599 |
| 62 | 9761596587 | 1057847755 | 16683756 | 230289842 | 1399235989 |
| 63 | 9782104875 | 1075055403 | 16299138 | 237386812 | 1397167324 |
| 64 | 9790122724 | 1091147494 | 16650471 | 229928585 | 1463076072 |

Edit:
2 things worth noting:

1. If I add padding to the inner loop so it won't fit in the uop cache I don't see this behavior until ~150 iterations.
2. Adding an `lfence` on with the padding in the outer loop changes N threshold to 31.

edit2: <s>Benchmark which clears branch history</s> The condition was reversed. It should be `cmove` not `cmovne`. With the fixed version any iteration count sees elevated **Branch Misses** at the same rate as above (1.67 * 10^9). This means the **LSD** is not itself causing **Branch Misses**, but leaves open the possibility that **LSD** is in some way defeating the **Branch Predictor** (what I believe to be the case).

```
static void BENCH_ATTR
bench(uint64_t inner_N) {
    uint64_t inner_loop_cnt, outer_loop_cnt;
    asm volatile(
        ".p2align 12\n"
        "movl   %k[outer_N], %k[outer_loop_cnt]\n"
        ".p2align   6\n"
        "1:\n"
        "testl  $3, %k[outer_loop_cnt]\n"
        "movl   $1000, %k[inner_loop_cnt]\n"
        THIS NEEDS TO BE CMOVE
        "cmovne   %k[inner_N], %k[inner_loop_cnt]\n"
        // Extra align surrounding inner loop so that the entire thing
        // doesn't execute out of LSD.
        ".p2align   10\n"
        "2:\n"
        "decl   %k[inner_loop_cnt]\n"
        "jnz    2b\n"
        ".p2align   10\n"
        "decl   %k[outer_loop_cnt]\n"
        "jnz    1b\n"
        : [ inner_loop_cnt ] "=&r"(inner_loop_cnt),
          [ outer_loop_cnt ] "=&r"(outer_loop_cnt)
        : [ inner_N ] "ri"(inner_N), [ outer_N ] "i"(outer_N)
        :);
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can use `taskset perf ...` so taskset isn't part of the workload you're profiling.  Also, if you [config](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519070/security-implications-of-changing-perf-event-paranoid) your `perf_event_paranoid` to `0` for example, you can avoid needing `sudo` on benchmark runs.

Comment: You might consider plotting branch misses on the right axis because the values are so small they are hard to see when they share an axis with "branches".

Answer (score 2):

This may be a coincidence; similar misprediction effects happen on Skylake (with recent microcode that disables the LSD<sup>1</sup>): an inner-loop count of about 22 or 23 is enough to stop its IT-TAGE predictor from learning the pattern of 21 taken, 1 not-taken for the inner-loop branch, in exactly this simple nested loop situation, last time I tested.

Choosing that iteration threshold for when to lock the loop down into the LSD might make some sense, or be a side-effect of your 1-uop loop and the LSD's ["unrolling" behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311872/is-performance-reduced-when-executing-loops-whose-uop-count-is-not-a-multiple-of) on Haswell and later to get multiple copies of tiny loops into the IDQ before locking it down, to reduce the impact of the loop not being a multiple of the pipeline width.

Footnote 1: I'm surprised your Whiskey Lake seems to have a working LSD; I thought LSD was still disabled in all Skylake derivatives, [at least including Coffee Lake](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/coffee_lake#Front-end), which was launched concurrently with [Whiskey Lake](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/whiskey_lake).

---

My test loop was two `dec/jne` loops nested simply, IIRC, but your code has padding *after* the inner loop. (Starting with a `jmp` because that's what a huge `.p2align` does.)  This puts the two loop branches at significantly different addresses.  Either of both of these differences may help them avoid aliasing or some other kind of interference, because I'm seeing mostly-correct predictions for many (but not all) counts much greater than 23.

With your test code on my i7-6700k, `lsd.uops` is always exactly 0 of course. **Compared to your Whiskey Lake data, only a few inner-loop counts produce high mispredict rates, e.g. 40, but not 50.**

So there might be some effect from the LSD on your WHL CPU, making it bad for some N values where SKL is fine.  (Assuming their IT-TAGE predictors are truly identical.)

e.g. with `perf stat ... -r 5 ./a.out` on Skylake (i7-6700k) with microcode revision 0xe2.

| N | count | rate | variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 59,602 | 0.02% of all branches | +- 10.85% |
| 20 | 192,307 | 0.05% of all branches | ( +- 44.60% ) |
| 21 | 79,853 | 0.02% of all branches | ( +- 14.16% ) |
| 30 | 136,308 | 0.02% of all branches | ( +- 18.57% ) |
| 31..32 | similar to N=34 |  | ( +- 2 or 3% ) |
| 33 | 22,415,089 | 3.71% of all branches | ( +- 0.11% ) |
| 34 | 91,483 | 0.01% of all branches | ( +- 2.36% ) |
| 35 (and 36..37 similar) | 98,806 | 0.02% of all branches | ( +- 2.75% ) |
| 38 | 33,517,630 | 4.87% of all branches | ( +- 0.05% ) |
| 39 | 102,077 | 0.01% of all branches | ( +- 1.96% ) |
| 40 | 33,458,267 | 4.64% of all branches | ( +- 0.06% ) |
| 41 | 116,241 | 0.02% of all branches | ( +- 6.86% ) |
| 42 | 22,376,562 | 2.96% of all branches | ( +- 0.01% ) |
| 43 | 116,713 | 0.02% of all branches | ( +- 5.25% ) |
| 44 | 174,834 | 0.02% of all branches | ( +- 35.08% ) |
| 45 | 124,555 | 0.02% of all branches | ( +- 5.36% ) |
| 46 | 135,838 | 0.02% of all branches | ( +- 9.95% ) |

These numbers are repeatable, it's not just system noise; the spikes of high mispredict counts are very real at those specific N values.  Probably some effect of the size / geometry of the IT-TAGE predictor's tables.

Other counters like `idq.ms_uops` and `idq.dsb_uops` scale mostly as expected, although `idq.ms_uops` is somewhat higher in the ones with more misses.  (That counts uops added to the IDQ *while the MS-ROM is active*, perhaps counting front-end work that happens while branch recovery is cleaning up the back-end?  It's a very different counter from legacy-decode `mite_uops`.)

With higher mispredict rates, `idq.dsb_uops` is quite a lot higher, I guess because the IDQ gets discarded and refilled on mispredicts.  Like `1,011,000,288` for N=42, vs. `789,170,126` for N=43.

Note the high variability for N=20, around that threshold near 23, but still a tiny overall miss rate, much lower than every time the inner loop exits.

This is surprising, and different from a loop without as much padding.

Comment: That may not be the case. If I add padding to the inner loop to defeat the LSD I don't see any increase in branch-misses until ~150 inner loop iterations.

Comment: Err, I buy I that the LSD is a red herring, but I don't see where the constants are coming from.

Comment: I updated the benchmark a bit (see edit) to basically try and reset the branch predictor of the inner loop (3/4 of the runs do 1000 which should get it to always predict taken, 1/4 do N). I see the same correspondence between LSD and branch-misses. I think if it was just N reaching the size of the branch history buffer we should not expect the clear jump at `N = 22`.

Comment: @Noah: The 22 or 23 transition threshold was with a much tighter loop; apparently that makes a difference because your test loop is different.  Update with some selected test data for my system.

Comment: Havent updated my firmware and bought the machine before the update. It does draw attention back to the LSD, however, if on your whiskey lake w/o the LSD you are seeing different rates. How stable are the rates if you use the same idea as my updated benchmark with flushing the branch history 3/4 of the iterations? If its just branch history buffer I would have expected that to produce a relatively stable branch-misses rate across all N.

Comment: @Noah: My machine is Skylake, although that's mostly microarchitecturally identical, except Whiskey Lake has HW fixes for Meltdown and L1TF, and Stepping 12 has extra mitigation for Spectre and Speculative Store Bypass.  https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/whiskey_lake#CPUID.

Comment: @Noah: Anyway, you don't need to update your mobo firmware, just install the Linux package `intel-ucode` or whatever your distro calls it, and make sure it's configured to have *Linux* update the firmware during early boot.  Although if WHL needed its LSD disabled, its initial firmware would have already had that; it didn't come out until after that fix was already in CPUs like Skylake-server.

Comment: @Noah: 3/4 of the runs do 1000 iterations: IT-TAGE indexes a prediction based on history of last several branches, it's definitely not simple.  I wouldn't be fully confident of that wiping out everything.

Comment: I see. What would you say as the best approach? Replace the padding with chain of jumps to fill the table?

Comment: @Noah: I don't know enough about IT-TAGE to know how to design experiments to figure out its parameters and do certain things. :/  Doing 1k iterations for 3/4 of the runs is a good idea; does it actually make a difference for you?  I wouldn't be *sure* of what that will do, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: It makes a difference in that the low bar for branch-misses is roughtly 2 * 10^6 but the high bar still stabalizes as 1.67 * 10^7.  I tested again with 63/64 for the 1k iteration and low from [0..20] with ~10^6. At N = 21 sharp rise again in LSD and 1.67 * 10^7 mispredicts. With 1023/1024 sharp rise at N = 22 (along with LSD). Doubtful that the LSD is the cause but there is some common thread that I think goes past just IT-TAGE. Btw do you know of any good reading for IT-TAGE? Google & Agner are not particularly helpful in finding anything.

Comment: @Noah: https://comparch.net/2013/06/30/why-tage-is-the-best/ is a brief intro and links a paper.   [Branch Prediction and the Performance of Interpreters -
Don’t Trust Folklore](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01100647/document) compares simulated IT-TAGE against real measurements on Sandybridge vs. Haswell, but doesn't go into a lot of detail about how IT-TAGE works.  (And the use-case is different: primarily an *indirect* branch as a grand-central dispatch in an interpreter loop.)

Comment: Those links got me in the right direction. Thanks! Two nice resources I found: [This CMU lecture](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15740-s17/www/lectures/L19-BranchPrediction.pdf) and [the origional paper](http://www.irisa.fr/caps/people/seznec/JILP-COTTAGE.pdf). Based on what I'm seeing TAGE you might be right that I wasnt clearing the history. Think one of the layers could have kept predictor for N.

Comment: Alright, confirmed it was the branch predictor. Guess the constants happen to correspond with the LSD. Big oof on my part as well. The conditions on my "defeat brand predictor" benchmark where reversed. instead of 3/4 1k, it was 1/4 1k....

Comment: I think what you said about "unrolling" in the LSD is somewhat related. If I pad the inner loop with a few `nop` instructions s.t that it can still fit in the LSD it will increase the bound where misprediction starts. Something about a `jcc` being unrolled by the LSD doesn't play well with the branch predictor but not sure what could be mechanism. It seems that the `pc` is somehow considered different in some sense but not sure how that could be.

Comment: @Noah: A predicted-taken uop is different from a predicted-not-taken uop (e.g. not-taken can run on more ports), so that prediction might get nailed down when it locks the uops down in the LSD.  Also keep in mind that changing the relative(?) addresses of branches can affect how they interfere with each other in the BPU, so it's hard to do controlled experiments.  Perhaps more smaller NOPs vs. fewer larger NOPs could let you keep all the branches at the same addresses while varying the LSD behaviour by changing how many uops in the inner loop.

Comment: Decided to just pad the second loop by same amount as first loop. Any overhead on outer loop should be neglidgable and keeps relative offset constants. Ill post a graph if I find any interesting results.

Comment: @Noah: I meant varying the uop count of the inner loop while holding its size in bytes constant, so the address of every branch (and every branch target) stays constant.  I guess you could try that with different absolute amounts of padding in different places to see if different layouts cause different interference effects.

Comment: Edit with results from the test. Pretty sure this is caused by the LSD and its not just some happenstance.

Comment: @Noah: Some of that EDIT / update stuff could go in a separate answer, instead of making such a long question.  That would be the best place for further experiments and especially for theories / inferences drawn from their results.

Comment: I could also cleanup the question and drop all edits buts #5 and add it is evidence that whatever is happening to the branch predictor is indeed caused by the LSD. Reason Im hesitant to write an answer is i really have no idea why this could be happening. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Noah: A tentative answer is fine.  You don't have to *accept* that answer.  You can even put in bold at the top of the answer "Results so far; more answers welcome" or something to that effect.

Comment: Wrote answer and cleaned up question. Sorry had to take away your checkmark, it was a bit premature but I think there is more too this.

Comment: @Noah: Yeah, that's fine, I was surprised you accepted it so early, when it was still just a total guess.

Comment: The relevant answer is really just the quote from the intel manual. Do you think I should move the "proof its the LSD" (or drop entirely) and make the answer just the quote?

Comment: @Noah: I don't think you should remove your other testing; it's useful to back up that interpretation of Intel's description with some testing. Intel has been known to be wrong in their manuals, or omit mention of other complications.  Not being able to break out of the LSD other than by branch mispredict is interesting; I guess that means it doesn't spend power on the BPU and recycles the predictions it had when uops went into the LSD, so it loses the ability to predict the loop exit for short inner loops.

Comment: @Noah:  Hmm, I forget when I tested and found that ~22 iteration inner-loop limit; I thought it was after microcode updates disabled the LSD, but if it was before; that could maybe explain it: LSD kicking in could have been what stopped the loop-exit from predicting correctly.

Comment: The manual explicitly mentions 20, but these as well point to 21-25. I'll edit and make it an approximate. I think breaking on mispredict also fundamentally makes sense with the design although is VERY annoying in this case (and basically any microbenchmark with a loop!)

Comment: @Noah: It might be interesting to try a microbenchmark with a single loop that has a simple repeating pattern for an  `if()` in the body, like every 3rd iteration there's a taken forward branch, so it's not going to be a multiple of the LSD unroll factor.  e.g. `dec edi` / `jnz skip_reset` / `mov edi, 3` / `skip_reset:`.  (That's actually taken mostly, occasionally not-taken, but I think the LSD can maybe still work if it jumps to a separate block and then back in a pattern.  Or does this defeat the LSD?  I forget.)

Comment: In my tests I found for very lower iteration counts it would run out of the **LSD** and have perfectly predicted branch. I think for just a `decl edi; jnz loop` iteration count was ~12, though adding `nop` to the inner loop body would decrease iteration count where this would work. i.e `loop: nop; decl edi; jnz loop` would leave **LSD** at ~10. So maybe there is a second case for tiny loops who can entirely unroll in the LSD.

Comment: @Noah: like the whole *outer* loop fits in the LSD, containing a fully-unrolled copy of the inner loop?

Comment: The entire nested loop runs out of the LSD for `iteration <= 11` and there are a neglible amount of branch misses. It will entirely runout of the LSD for `iterations = 11` as long as the `inner loop uops <= FE width` (5 on ICL). If I increase inner loop uops to 6 can only get this low branch miss / entirely LSD with `iterations = 9-10` (it varies, 10 is 25% Uop Cache, 75% LSD but 9 is 100% LSD). The interesting thing is after `inner loop uops > FE width` each additional uop changes the iteration threshold, but `inner loop uops <= FE width` are all the same. Sorry for confusion in last comment!

Comment: So yeah, given how iteration count + nops affect how it runs out of the LSD I think its the outer loop + unrolled inner loop is in LSD. Interesting that you essentially get free unrolling for small constant loops at runtime.

Comment: @Noah: Not free, the loop branch still has to go through the issue/rename stage.  The LSD usually doesn't make a difference to front-end bottlenecks for tiny loops.  Real unrolling reduces loop overhead.

Comment: Can you think of any no overhead way to defeat this? I'm finding that on some of my old code I mistuned alignment when the extra nops from say aligning a loop was the difference between hitting this extra branch miss or not. Only thing I can think of is to make all my benchmarks use random(ish) data but that has overhead in itself, adding a constant number of nops (but that defeats code size optimizations), or adding empty `call; ret` in code path to defeat the LSD. Any ideas? (or maybe deserves its own question?).

Comment: @Noah: Is it a significant slowdown?  Can you just unroll more so the loop doesn't fit in the LSD?  But that might introduce more unpredictable branching in the loop prologue.  Mis-predicting before you get the loop iterations into the back-end is probably a lot worse than after.  (Unless the code before the loop could equally well fill up the back-end with a long critical-path to chew on.)  Also keep in mind that hyperthreading can hide a lot of the cost of a mispredict if your code is threaded.  I wouldn't try to defeat the LSD with a call;ret, that would be worse for CPUs without LSDs.

Comment: Graph 3 my origional question has CPU cycles. The extra branch misses do cause a spike in time. This test code also probably about as ideal as it gets for hiding the code of a mispredict because `decl` can speculate ahead easily (better though if there where some high latency instructions in the loop). In a data dependent situation (i.e pointer chasing till `NULL`) will probably be a lot worse.

Comment: @Noah: yeah, in this fully artificial benchmark sure it costs cycles, because there are no data dependency chains or cache misses for the back-end to be crunching during branch recovery. Also, your workload contains a lot of NOPs outside that inner loop, so any mispredict loses cycles of front-end throughput.  `dec/jnz` can only "speculate ahead" when there's a slower loop body; taken branches (including macro-fused) have 1/clock throughput.   Is your real use-case also that high throughput, like would come close to saturating the front-end uops / clock limit if not for mispredicts?

Comment: Okay fair. You might not see this in ideal mispredict hiding circumstances. But I think it can (and does) have an affect in real cases. Noticed this first time when benchmarking some stuff from GLIBC optimized x86_64 library. For example current strchr implementation has serious performance drop off at size = 2305 in benchmarks that loop through exact same size (as glibc currently does for their benchmarks).

Comment: Hey, this is totally unrelated but if you have a minute can you take a look at [this glibc patch for memset](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-April/125214.html). The maintainer had me replace `sall` with `andl` because `andl` has better tput. But I'm pretty sure its actively harmful. 1) It costs 16 bytes of code. 2) It makes it so that `movl $-1, %ecx` in the non page cross case is decoded on cycle 2 instead of cycle 1 essentially costing a cycle on the critical path. The only case I can see is that in page_cross `sall` will compete with `jcc` for p06. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231345/discussion-between-peter-cordes-and-noah).

Comment: something interesting I've been noticing is that loops aligned to 16 bytes enter the LSD slightly faster. Just thought I'd note that.

Comment: this is totally unrelated but I shared a document with you a while ago on some reverse engineering of apple m1. Any chance you have a link? I can't refind it.

Comment: @Noah: Yeah, I bookmarked the google drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrMYCZMnhsGP4o3H33ioAUKL_bjuJSPt/view .  IIRC, it was attributed to Maynard Handley.  Yup,  https://www.techspot.com/news/91275-learn-all-about-apple-m1-350-page-deep.html is an article about it.

Comment: totally unrelated, but do you know when the domain cross penalty for `unpckpd` -> `unpckdq` was fixed? Is it HWL+ (blends), SKL+(shuffle) or something different?

Comment: @Noah: Was there ever a penalty on Sandybridge-family CPUs?  I thought all shuffles could forward to or from int/FP with no penalty on SnB.

Comment: I think it varies a bit. So according to [Agner](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf#page=133) there is not bypass delay on `shufps` being misused, but there is a delay for `shufd` on SnB. By Haswell [he says no more delay on any shuffle](https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf#page=144). Does "shuffle" include unpack? This is for LLVM. We have [NoBypassDelayShuffle](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Target/X86/X86.td#L552) starting as HSW.

Comment: we have a new pass [X86FixupInstTuning](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Target/X86/X86FixupInstTuning.cpp) that essentially replaces bad codegen that exists because modifying the DAG selector isn't effective, and I want to change the replacement of [`unpck{lo|hi}pd` -> `unpck{lo|hi}dq` (currently we do `shuf{ps|pd}`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Target/X86/X86FixupInstTuning.cpp#L226). But haven't been able to track down the set of CPU families it safe for.

Comment: @Noah: Thanks, I'd forgotten that detail. `punpckhqdq` and `unpckhpd` are clearly shuffles.  They run only on port 5, and they move elements to different positions in the output than they were in the input so aren't just a blend.  From Agner's examples for SnB/IvB, I'd guess most or all shuffles can forward to/from SIMD-integer ops like `paddd`, but only FP shuffles can forward with zero latency to FP instructions, on the theory that a shuffle execution unit is expensive, so it's cheaper to just have one and cross-connect it for forwarding instead of having separate units in separate domains.

Comment: @Noah: Just a guess, not tested; I have an old SnB laptop I could boot from USB.  Oh, also I was forgetting, SnB had a 2nd shuffle unit for integer shuffles because it only had AVX1, so its integer shuffle units only needed to be 128-bit wide.  Only the port 5 shuffle unit was 256-bit, and only it could handle FP shuffles.  (Haswell dropped the extra shuffle unit, limiting all shuffles to 1/clock throughput until Ice Lake allowed some 256-bit shuffles to run 2/clock on port 1/5).  I'm sure that's related to there being bypass latency between FP math and integer shuffles on SnB.

Comment: re:"Thanks, I'd forgotten that detail. punpckhqdq and unpckhpd are clearly shuffles. They run only on port 5", realized that is somewhat missing a explanation for why on ICX only `unpckhpd` still only runs on p5, but all other shuffles (and `punckhqdq`) run on `p15`.

Comment: @Noah: Lots of shuffles on ICX are p5 only, including `palignr`, `vpermd`, `unpckhps`, `unpcklps` as well as `pd` unpacks.  It is a bit odd that integer unpacks run on p15 while FP unpacks only run on p5, though, especially when shufps and shufpd run on p15 and can do the same shuffle as `unpckl/h ps/pd`.

Answer (score 2):

### Reason

- The cause of the spike in **Branch Misses** is caused by the inner loop running out of the **LSD**.
- The reason the **LSD** causes an extra branch miss for low iteration counts is that the "stop" condition on the **LSD** is a branch miss.

From [Intel Optimization Manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-optimization-reference-manual.html) Page 86.

> The loop is sent to allocation 5 µops per cycle. After 45 out of the 46 µops are sent, in the next cycle only
> a single µop is sent, which means that in that cycle, 4 of the allocation slots are wasted. This pattern
> repeats itself, until the loop is exited by a misprediction. Hardware loop unrolling minimizes the number
> of wasted slots during LSD.

Essentially what is happening is that when low enough iteration counts run out of the **Uop Cache** they are perfectly predictable. But when they run out of the **LSD** since the built in stop condition for the **LSD** is a branch mispredict, we see an extra branch miss for every iteration of the outer loop. I guess the takeaway is don't let nested loops execute out of the **LSD**. Note that **LSD** only kicks in after ~[20, 25] iterations so an inner loop with < 20 iterations will run optimally.

### Benchmark

All benchmarks are run on either **[Icelake](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196597/intel-core-i7-1065g7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html)**

The new benchmark is essentially the same as the one in the origional post but at the advise of @PeterCordes I added a fixed byte size but varying number of nops in the inner loop. The idea is fixed length so that there is no change in how the branches may alias in the **BHT (Branch History Table)** but varying the number of nops to sometimes defeat the **LSD**.

I used **124 bytes of nop padding** so that the nop padding + size of **`decl; jcc` would be 128 bytes total**.

The benchmark code is as follows:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef INNER_NOPS
#error "INNER_NOPS must be defined"
#endif

         
#define BENCH_ATTR __attribute__((noinline, noclone, aligned(4096)))

static const uint64_t outer_N   = (1UL << 24);
static const uint64_t bht_shift = 4;
static const uint64_t bht_mask  = (1023 << bht_shift);

#define NOP1   ".byte 0x90\n"
#define NOP2   ".byte 0x66,0x90\n"
#define NOP3   ".byte 0x0f,0x1f,0x00\n"
#define NOP4   ".byte 0x0f,0x1f,0x40,0x00\n"
#define NOP5   ".byte 0x0f,0x1f,0x44,0x00,0x00\n"
#define NOP6   ".byte 0x66,0x0f,0x1f,0x44,0x00,0x00\n"
#define NOP7   ".byte 0x0f,0x1f,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00\n"
#define NOP8   ".byte 0x0f,0x1f,0x84,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00\n"
#define NOP9   ".byte 0x66,0x0f,0x1f,0x84,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00\n"
#define NOP10  ".byte 0x66,0x66,0x0f,0x1f,0x84,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00\n"
#define NOP11  ".byte 0x66,0x66,0x66,0x0f,0x1f,0x84,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00\n"


static void BENCH_ATTR
bench(uint64_t inner_N) {
    uint64_t inner_loop_cnt, outer_loop_cnt, tmp;
    asm volatile(
        ".p2align 12\n"
        "movl   %k[outer_N], %k[outer_loop_cnt]\n"
        ".p2align   6\n"
        "1:\n"
        "movl   %k[inner_N], %k[inner_loop_cnt]\n"
        ".p2align   10\n"
        "2:\n"
        // This is defined in "inner_nops.h" with the necessary padding.
        INNER_NOPS
        "decl   %k[inner_loop_cnt]\n"
        "jnz    2b\n"
        ".p2align   10\n"
        "decl   %k[outer_loop_cnt]\n"
        "jnz    1b\n"
        : [ inner_loop_cnt ] "=&r"(inner_loop_cnt),
          [ outer_loop_cnt ] "=&r"(outer_loop_cnt), [ tmp ] "=&r"(tmp)
        : [ inner_N ] "ri"(inner_N), [ outer_N ] "i"(outer_N),
          [ bht_mask ] "i"(bht_mask), [ bht_shift ] "i"(bht_shift)
        :);
}
// gcc -O3 -march=native -mtune=native lsd-branchmiss.c -o lsd-branchmiss
int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    assert(argc > 1);
    uint64_t inner_N = atoi(argv[1]);
    bench(inner_N);
    return 0;
}
```

### Tests

I tested `nop count = [0, 39]`.

Note that `nop count = 1` would not be only 1 nop in the inner loop but actually the following:

```
#define INNER_NOPS NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP10 NOP3 NOP1
```

To reach the full 128 byte padding.

### Results

- At `nop count <= 32` the inner loop is able to run out of the **LSD** and we consistently see elevant **Branch Misses** when `Iterations` is large enough that it does so. Note that the elevated **Branch Misses** number corresponds 1-1 with the number of `outer loop iterations`. For these numbers `outer loop iterations = 2^24`
- At `nop count > 32` the loop has to many uops for the **LSD** and runs out of the **Uop Cache**. Here we do not see a consistent elevated  **Branch Misses** until `Iterations` becomes to large for its **BHT** entry to store its entire history.

### nop count > 32 (No LSD)

Once there are too many nops for the **LSD** the number of **Branch Misses** stays relatively low with a few consistent spikes until `Iterations = 146` where **Branch Misses** spike to number of `outer loop iterations` (2 ^ 24 in this case) and remain constants. My guess is that is the upper bound on history the **BHT** is able to store.

Below is a graph of **Branch Misses (Y)** versus **Iterations (X)** for `nop count = [33, 39]`:

[image: hi-bm]

All of the lines follow the same patterns and have the same spikes. The large spikes to `outer loop iterations` before 146 are at `Iterations = [42, 70, 79, 86, 88]`. This is consistently reproducible. I am not sure what is special about these values.

**The key point**, however, is that for the most cast for `Iterations = [20, 145]` **Branch Misses** is relatively low indicating that the entire inner loop is being predicted correctly.

### nop count <= 32 (LSD)

This data is a bit more noising bit all of the different `nop count` follow roughly the same trend of spiking initialing to within a factor of 2 of `outer loop iterations` **Branch Misses** at `Iterations = [21, 25]` (note this is 2-3 orders of magnitude) at the same time the **lsd.oups** spiked by 4-5 orders of magnitude.

There is also a trend between `nop count` and what `iteration` value **Branch Misses** stablize at `outer loop iterations` with a [Pearson Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) of `0.81`. for `nop count = [0, 32]` the stablization point is in range `iterations = [15, 34]`.

Below is a graph of **Branch Misses (Y)** versus **Iterations (X)** for `nops = [0, 32]`:

[image: lo-bm]

Generally, with some noise, all of the different `nop count` follow the same trend. As well they follow the same trend when compared with **lsd.uops**.

Below is a table with **nop** and the [Pearson Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) between **Branch Misses** and **lsd.uop** and **idq.dsb_uops** respectively.

| nop | lsd | uop cache |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.961 | -0.041 |
| 1 | 0.955 | -0.081 |
| 2 | 0.919 | -0.122 |
| 3 | 0.918 | -0.299 |
| 4 | 0.947 | -0.117 |
| 5 | 0.934 | -0.298 |
| 6 | 0.894 | -0.329 |
| 7 | 0.907 | -0.308 |
| 8 | 0.91 | -0.322 |
| 9 | 0.915 | -0.316 |
| 10 | 0.877 | -0.342 |
| 11 | 0.908 | -0.28 |
| 12 | 0.874 | -0.281 |
| 13 | 0.875 | -0.523 |
| 14 | 0.87 | -0.513 |
| 15 | 0.889 | -0.522 |
| 16 | 0.858 | -0.569 |
| 17 | 0.89 | -0.507 |
| 18 | 0.858 | -0.537 |
| 19 | 0.844 | -0.565 |
| 20 | 0.816 | -0.459 |
| 21 | 0.862 | -0.537 |
| 22 | 0.848 | -0.556 |
| 23 | 0.852 | -0.552 |
| 24 | 0.85 | -0.561 |
| 25 | 0.828 | -0.573 |
| 26 | 0.857 | -0.559 |
| 27 | 0.802 | -0.372 |
| 28 | 0.762 | -0.425 |
| 29 | 0.721 | -0.112 |
| 30 | 0.736 | -0.047 |
| 31 | 0.768 | -0.174 |
| 32 | 0.847 | -0.129 |

Which should generally indicate that there is a strong correlation between **LSD** and **Branch Misses** and no meaningful relationship between the **Uop Cache** and branch misses.

### Overall

Generally I think it is clear that when the inner loop executing out of the **LSD** is what is causing the **Branch Misses** until `Iterations` becomes too large for the **BHT** entry's history. For the `N = [33, 39]` save the explained spikes we don't see elevated **Branch Misses** but we do for the `N = [0, 32]` case and the only difference I can tell is the **LSD**.