# Base virtual address for .text segment of PIE ELF executable on linux x86_64

Tags: linux, linker, elf

I see that .text segment of ELF files that linked with -pie argument when loaded into memory locates somewhere in virtual memory addresses like 0x00005xxxxxxxxxxx on linux x86_64. I've checked several running processes and it seems that .text segment's address *all* of them has prefix 0x00005, I could not find any one with 0x00004 prefix for example.

Is there any reason why dynamic linker chooses this address range (0x00005xxxxxxxxxxx) to locate .text segment? Why it does not select some addresses starting from 4Mb+ like binaries linked without -pie argument?

Comment: ASLR? Change in dynamic loader or mmap? Why do you care that it's not "4Mb+"? (whatever that may mean)

Comment: Well, ASLR explains why .text segment's virtual address varies between executable launches, but does not explain why _all_ PIE executables in my linux x86_64 system have .text segments in addresses like 0x00005xxxxxxxxxxx. Why there is no binaries with .text segment at address 0x00004xxxxxxxxxxx?

Comment: By 4Mb+ I mean that default GNU linker for calls without -pie argument links executable so .text segment starts from 0x400000 (you can examine /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ldscripts/elf_x86_64.x from binutils package, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any reason why dynamic linker chooses this address range (0x00005xxxxxxxxxxx) to locate .text segment?

The dynamic linker has *nothing to do with this*.

The executable is `mmap`ed by the kernel before the first user-space instruction executes (that instruction is the `_start` in the dynamic loader for dynamically linked binaries), as part of executing the `execve` system call.

So you have to look in kernel sources for explanation of why PIE binaries end up in the `0x5...` range.

Looking in `fs/binfmt_elf.c` you can see that it uses `ELF_ET_DYN_BASE`, which is defined in `arch/x86/include/asm/elf.h` as

```
#define ELF_ET_DYN_BASE         (mmap_is_ia32() ? 0x000400000UL : \
                                                  (DEFAULT_MAP_WINDOW / 3 * 2))
```

The `DEFAULT_MAP_WINDOW` is itself coming from `arch/x86/include/asm/page_64_types.h`:

```
#define DEFAULT_MAP_WINDOW ((1UL << 47) - PAGE_SIZE)
```

Putting this all together: `(1UL << 47) - 4096 == 0x7ffffffff000`; `0x7ffffffff000 / 3 * 2 == 0x555555554aaa`.

P.S. Note that `.text` is a section, *not* a segment. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382477/50617).