# Why does GCC create a shared object instead of an executable binary according to file?

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, position-independent-code

I have a library I am building. All of my objects compile and link successively when I run either one of:
`ar rcs lib/libryftts.a $^`

`gcc -shared $^ -o lib/libryftts.so`

in my Makefile. I also am able to successfully install them into `/usr/local/lib`
When I test the file with nm, all the functions are there.
My problem is that when I run `gcc testing/test.c -lryftts -o test && file ./test` or `gcc testing/test.c lib/libryftts.a -o test && file ./test`
it says:

`test: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object` instead of `test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable` as I would expect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `test.c` containing `main`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes it contains main.

Comment: Sounds strange. But probably need more info to diagnose the problem. Suggest you create a minimal test case and post the exact code and build commands used to produce the problem. Also, you may want to run the last compilation line with `gcc -v` to see exactly what commands and options gcc really ends up using.

Comment: Related: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing.

It sounds like your GCC is configured to build `-pie` binaries by default. These binaries really *are* shared libraries (of type `ET_DYN`), except they run just like a normal executable would.

So your should just run your binary, and (if it works) not worry about it.

Or you could link your binary with `gcc -no-pie ...` and that should produce a non-`PIE` executable of type `ET_EXEC`, for which `file` will say `ELF 64-bit LSB executable`.

Comment: Upon runinng `gcc ... -v` I did see -pie in the config. This fixed what I was seeing. Thanks for the info!

Comment: For anyone (like me) who is compiling with [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) - you need to add `-no-pie` to **Linker Settings → Other linker options**, _not_ **Compiler settings → Other compiler options** as you might expect - the latter adds `-no-pie` when compiling the individual C files, but not when building the final executable.

Comment: If you're going to use `-no-pie`, you should also use `-fno-pie` to get slightly more efficient code-gen.  (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)

Comment: How do I tell my compiler to compile with -no-pie by default?

Comment: @dylan You would have to build your own compiler. When you `configure` it, don't specify `--enable-default-pie` and you'll be all set.

Comment: BTW, I couldn't control myself so I understood `file` behavior in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/why-does-gcc-create-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary-according-to/55704865#55704865 Linux is a barrage of bugs and random bits. What am I doing with my life?

Comment: `ET_DYN` is really only a trick to make the loader load it at a non-absolute address.

Answer (score 38):

**`file` 5.36 says it clearly**

`file` 5.36 actually prints it clearly if the executable is PIE or not as shown at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/how-to-test-whether-a-linux-binary-was-compiled-as-position-independent-code/435038#435038

For example, a PIE executable shows as:

> main.out: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped

and a non-PIE one as:

> main.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped

The feature was introduced in 5.33 but it did just a simple `chmod +x` check. Before that it just printed `shared object` for PIE.

In 5.34, it was meant to start checking the more specialized `DF_1_PIE` ELF metadata, but due to a bug in the implementation at commit [9109a696f3289ba00eaa222fd432755ec4287e28](https://github.com/file/file/commit/9109a696f3289ba00eaa222fd432755ec4287e28#diff-bc5c24ef9f39a5f4963ca28ecbc645b3R1057) it actually broke things and showed GCC PIE executables as `shared objects`.

The bug was fixed in 5.36 at commit [03084b161cf888b5286dbbcd964c31ccad4f64d9](https://github.com/file/file/commit/03084b161cf888b5286dbbcd964c31ccad4f64d9#diff-bc5c24ef9f39a5f4963ca28ecbc645b3L1098).

The bug is present in particular in Ubuntu 18.10 which has `file` 5.34.

It does not manifest itself when linking assembly code with `ld -pie` because of a coincidence.

Source code breakdown is shown in the "`file` 5.36 source code analysis" section of this answer.

**The Linux kernel 5.0 determines if ASLR can be used based on `ET_DYN`**

The root cause of the `file` "confusion", is that both [PIE executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld/51308031#51308031) and shared libraries are position independent and can be placed in randomized memory locations.

At [fs/binfmt_elf.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/fs/binfmt_elf.c) the kernel only accepts those two types of ELF files:

```
/* First of all, some simple consistency checks */
if (interp_elf_ex->e_type != ET_EXEC &&
        interp_elf_ex->e_type != ET_DYN)
        goto out;
```

Then, only for `ET_DYN` does it set the `load_bias` to something that is not zero. The `load_bias` is then what determines the ELF offset: [How is the address of the text section of a PIE executable determined in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343596/how-is-the-address-of-the-text-section-of-a-pie-executable-determined-in-linux/51343797#51343797)

```
/*
 * If we are loading ET_EXEC or we have already performed
 * the ET_DYN load_addr calculations, proceed normally.
 */
if (loc->elf_ex.e_type == ET_EXEC || load_addr_set) {
        elf_flags |= elf_fixed;
} else if (loc->elf_ex.e_type == ET_DYN) {
        /*
         * This logic is run once for the first LOAD Program
         * Header for ET_DYN binaries to calculate the
         * randomization (load_bias) for all the LOAD
         * Program Headers, and to calculate the entire
         * size of the ELF mapping (total_size). (Note that
         * load_addr_set is set to true later once the
         * initial mapping is performed.)
         *
         * There are effectively two types of ET_DYN
         * binaries: programs (i.e. PIE: ET_DYN with INTERP)
         * and loaders (ET_DYN without INTERP, since they
         * _are_ the ELF interpreter). The loaders must
         * be loaded away from programs since the program
         * may otherwise collide with the loader (especially
         * for ET_EXEC which does not have a randomized
         * position). For example to handle invocations of
         * "./ld.so someprog" to test out a new version of
         * the loader, the subsequent program that the
         * loader loads must avoid the loader itself, so
         * they cannot share the same load range. Sufficient
         * room for the brk must be allocated with the
         * loader as well, since brk must be available with
         * the loader.
         *
         * Therefore, programs are loaded offset from
         * ELF_ET_DYN_BASE and loaders are loaded into the
         * independently randomized mmap region (0 load_bias
         * without MAP_FIXED).
         */
        if (elf_interpreter) {
                load_bias = ELF_ET_DYN_BASE;
                if (current->flags & PF_RANDOMIZE)
                        load_bias += arch_mmap_rnd();
                elf_flags |= elf_fixed;
        } else
                load_bias = 0;
```

I confirm this experimentally at: [What is the -fPIE option for position-independent executables in gcc and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld/51308031#51308031)

**`file` 5.36 behaviour breakdown**

After studying how `file` works from its source. We will conclude that:

- if `Elf32_Ehdr.e_type == ET_EXEC`

  - print `executable`
- else if `Elf32_Ehdr.e_type == ET_DYN`

  - if `DT_FLAGS_1` dynamic section entry is present

    - if `DF_1_PIE` is set in `DT_FLAGS_1`:

      - print `pie executable`
    - else

      - print `shared object`
  - else

    - if file is executable by user, group or others

      - print `pie executable`
    - else

      - print `shared object`

And here are some experiments that confirm that:

```
Executable generation        ELF type  DT_FLAGS_1  DF_1_PIE  chdmod +x      file 5.36
---------------------------  --------  ----------  --------  -------------- --------------
gcc -fpie -pie               ET_DYN    y           y         y              pie executable
gcc -fno-pie -no-pie         ET_EXEC   n           n         y              executable
gcc -shared                  ET_DYN    n           n         y              pie executable
gcc -shared                  ET_DYN    n           n         n              shared object
ld                           ET_EXEC   n           n         y              executable
ld -pie --dynamic-linker     ET_DYN    y           y         y              pie executable
ld -pie --no-dynamic-linker  ET_DYN    y           y         y              pie executable
```

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, GCC 8.2.0, Binutils 2.31.1.

The full test example for for each type of experiment is described at:

- `gcc -pie` and `gcc -no-pie`: [What is the -fPIE option for position-independent executables in gcc and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld/51308031#51308031)

  Keep in mind that `-pie` is set on by default since Ubuntu 17.10, related: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)
- `gcc -shared` (`.so` shared library): https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/b80ccb4a842db52d719a16d3716b02b684ebbf11/shared_library/basic
- `ld` experiments: [How to create a statically linked position independent executable ELF in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664494/how-to-create-a-statically-linked-position-independent-executable-elf-in-linux)

`ELF type` and `DF_1_PIE` are determined respectively with:

```
readelf --file-header main.out | grep Type
readelf --dynamic     main.out | grep FLAGS_1
```

**`file` 5.36 source code analysis**

The key file to analyse is [magic/Magdir/elf](https://github.com/file/file/blob/FILE5_36/magic/Magdir/elf).

This magic format determines file types depending only on the values of bytes at fixed positions.

The format itself is documented at:

```
man 5 magic
```

So at this point you will want to have the following documents handy:

- http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf ELF standard at the ELF header section
- http://www.cirosantilli.com/elf-hello-world/#elf-header my ELF file format introduction and breakdown

Towards the end of the file, we see:

```
0       string          \177ELF         ELF
!:strength *2
>4      byte            0               invalid class
>4      byte            1               32-bit
>4      byte            2               64-bit
>5      byte            0               invalid byte order
>5      byte            1               LSB
>>0     use             elf-le
>5      byte            2               MSB
>>0     use             \^elf-le
```

`\177ELF` are the 4 magic bytes at the start of every ELF file. `\177` is the octal for `0x7F`.

Then by comparing with the `Elf32_Ehdr` struct from the standard, we see that byte 4 (the 5th byte, the first one after the magic identifier), determines the ELF class:

```
e_ident[EI_CLASSELFCLASS]
```

and some of its possible values are:

```
ELFCLASS32 1
ELFCLASS64 2
```

In `file` source then, we have:

```
1 32-bit
2 64-bit
```

and `32-bit` and `64-bit` are the strings that `file` outputs to stdout!

So now we search for `shared object` in that file, and we are led to:

```
0       name            elf-le
>16     leshort         0               no file type,
!:mime  application/octet-stream
>16     leshort         1               relocatable,
!:mime  application/x-object
>16     leshort         2               executable,
!:mime  application/x-executable
>16     leshort         3               ${x?pie executable:shared object},
```

So this `elf-le` is some kind of identifier that gets included on the previous part of the code.

Byte 16 is exactly the ELF type:

```
Elf32_Ehdr.e_type
```

and some of its values are:

```
ET_EXEC 2
ET_DYN  3
```

Therefore, `ET_EXEC` always gets printed as `executable`.

`ET_DYN` however has two possibilities depending on `${x`:

- `pie executable`
- `shared object`

`${x` asks: are the file executable or not by either user, group or other? If yes, show `pie executable`, else `shared object`.

This expansion is done in the `varexpand` function in [`src/softmagic.c`](https://github.com/file/file/blob/FILE5_36/src/softmagic.c#L521):

```
static int
varexpand(struct magic_set *ms, char *buf, size_t len, const char *str)
{
    [...]
            case 'x':
                    if (ms->mode & 0111) {
                            ptr = t;
                            l = et - t;
                    } else {
                            ptr = e;
                            l = ee - e;
                    }
                    break;
```

There is, however, one more hack! In [`src/readelf.c`](https://github.com/file/file/blob/FILE5_36/src/readelf.c#L1104) function `dodynamic`, if the `DT_FLAGS_1` flags entry of the dynamic section (`PT_DYNAMIC`) is present, then the permissions in `st->mode` are overridden by the presence or absence of the `DF_1_PIE` flag:

```
case DT_FLAGS_1:
        if (xdh_val & DF_1_PIE)
                ms->mode |= 0111;
        else
                ms->mode &= ~0111;
        break;
```

The bug in 5.34 is that the initial code was written as:

```
    if (xdh_val == DF_1_PIE)
```

which means that if another flag was set, which GCC does by default due to `DF_1_NOW`, the executable showed as `shared object`.

The `DT_FLAGS_1` flags entry is not described in the ELF standard so it must be a Binutils extension.

That flag has no uses in the Linux kernel 5.0 or glibc 2.27, so I seems to be purely informative to indicate that a file is PIE or not.