# Ubuntu 17.04 C++ project compilation output wrong type

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, g++

I upgraded yesterday Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 and made a new compliation of my C++ projects. But it ouputs me a shared object file and it supposed to output an executable file of course.
I can execute it from command line but I can't launch the soft from the UI. It worked well in version 16.04.

Here is the end of the compilation:

```
echo Linking wxFlasher...
mkdir -p /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/out_gcc/releaseu/
rm -f /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/out_gcc/releaseu/wxFlasher
g++  -s -o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/out_gcc/releaseu/wxFlasher /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Main/Application.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Main/ResourceManager.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Main/Event.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Main/Thread.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Main/Utils.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/HMI/MainFrame.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/HMI/PnlFlasher.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/HMI/DlgAbout.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/HMI/PnlUpdater.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/HMI/PnlDump.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/HMI/PnlRegen.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/PlfManagement.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/UpdaterThread.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/UpdaterFactory.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/UartUpdaterProtocol.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/UartBootloaderProtocol.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/UsbUpdaterProtocol.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/UsbBootloaderProtocol.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/UsbOmap3630Protocol.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/TestProtocolThread.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/RegenProtocolThread.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Protocol/posix_crc.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Communication/libusb.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Communication/Uart.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Config/ProductCfg.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Config/ProductXml.o /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/build_gcc/releaseu/Config/UpdaterCfg.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0
```

Any ideas ?

**EDIT :**

Here is the output of `file` command:

```
wxFlasher: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=3c57f7ee667e4ba8be74a0392d9574a91918fa0e, not stripped
```

And here is the output of `g++ -v` command:

```
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.0 20170406 (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2)
```

Comment: Your linkage command, if successful, will output an executable `/home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/out_gcc/releaseu/wxFlasher`.
You've offered no evidence that it outputs an SO. The fact that you *can* execute it
from the commandline suggests that it is an executable, not an SO.

Comment: @MikeKinghan I edited the question. sorry for the french

Comment: Please add to your post the output of `file /home/barnaud/dev/wxFlasher/wxFlasher/out_gcc/releaseu/wxFla‌​sher`.
That will definitively show whether or not the file is an executable or SO.

Comment: Done @MikeKinghan

Comment: You are quite right. And this is reproducible from scratch? If so it is
quite beyond me. It looks as if `-s` is being parsed as `-shared` (which
would be insane)  Try removing the `-s`. Let's also see the output of
`g++ --version`

Comment: Look what I found : [GCC creates a shared object instead of an executable binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/gcc-creates-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary). Not sure what to do with this

Comment: Well spotted. So this could to be an Ubuntu decision as of 17.04 to configure
GCC to generate PIE binaries by default. Or it could be
an Ubuntu 17.04 cockup. I don't know. I'm still with 16.04 LTS.
I'm afraid I can't help with the UI launch problem it's
giving you.

Comment: I think that "interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" in the "file" output indicates that the file is executable.  It would be interesting to see the output of "g++ -v".

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud - I see "--enable-default-pie" in the output from "g++ -v".  I think this:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/871926/impossible-to-launch-graphic-executables-in-nautilus/895112 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/fpie-position-independent-executable-option-gcc-ld may help you.