# ELF file type - ET_EXEC and ET_DYN

Tags: x86, elf

Alright, as far as I know **ET_EXEC** is used to indicate that the file is an executable whereas **ET_DYN** indicates that the file is a shared library. So to be sure I wrote a simple program in C, the problem however is that **readelf -h** is yielding the following:

```
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Class:                             ELF64
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  .
  .
  .
```

I thought this had something to do with the compiler I used so I did the same with some utilities in */bin* but unfortunately got the same results. So here's the question: **Why is readelf identifying executables as shared libraries?**

Comment: Use `-static` to generate an `ET_EXEC`, by default GCC generates shared objects so they can be relocated. This entangles with PIE, x86_64 and, a bit, ASRL.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: even `gcc -no-pie` makes an ELF executable rather than shared object, because ASLR for executables is sort of a hack using existing capabilities of the dynamic linker to deal with shared objects that have an ELF entry point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is readelf identifying executables as shared libraries?

Because it *is* (a special kind of) shared library. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522357/50617).

Comment: I also wrote an answer with some details about PIE executables, at [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427), but I did mention that `file a.out` shows "executable" for `gcc -no-pie` but "shared object" for PIE executables, because that's what they are.