# I have questions about gdb memory address

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, 32-bit

When I use gcc to compile a C++ program to a 32 bit and I run it through gdb. When I disassemble the main function the gdb reads out the memory addresses EXAMPLE: 0x585583d0 and in other peoples examples of 32 bit it reads out  0x080483d0. Im using Kali linux and am wondering if its just because its a different distribution or am I missing some C libraries?

Comment: What is the real problem you are facing? Why do you believe the address should be different?

Comment: No just curious

Comment: Why do you say "instead"? Why don't you think the address should be `0xDEADBEEF`?

Comment: No I've seen examples that have address starting with 0x08 and mine are 0x56 and I was just wondering why, thats it. Its just question. Its not getting in the way of anything for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am wondering if its just because its a different distribution or am I missing some C libraries?

This is because you built a [position independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables), while other people didn't.

The default load address for non-PIE binaries on 32-bit x86 systems is `0x08048000`. The default load address for PIE binaries under GDB is somewhere in the `0x5855....` region (it can be very random outside of GDB; if you `set disable-randomization off`, you'll observe that the executable starts "jumping around" to different addresses).

Some newer distributions default to building PIE binaries. You can avoid this with:

```
gcc -no-pie main.c
```

The resulting binary should now start around `0x08048xxx`.

You can check whether you have a PIE binary or not with `file a.out` -- it will say `executable` for non-PIE binary, and `shared library` for a PIE binary. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/gcc-creates-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary).