# Compiling with ASLR(-pie) causes the executable to be seen as shared library

Tags: aslr

I am trying to add [security flags](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/03/21/compiler-and-linker-flags-gcc/) to an executable but it seem that when compiling with `-pie` (as linker flags), the `file` tool sees it as a shared library, although I can run it without problems.
Is this normal? Can this be fixed?

I am using `add_link_options(-pie)` (so all CMake executables can benefit)

`untitled3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=f33e240db8bf52c2566b2cad14b4be67fdb6b35a, with debug_info, not stripped`

LE: it seems it was a bug in `file` tool, fixed [here](https://github.com/file/file/commit/03084b161cf888b5286dbbcd964c31ccad4f64d9#diff-bc5c24ef9f39a5f4963ca28ecbc645b3L1098):

Comment: This is normal. Old versions of `file` can't tell the difference between a position-independent executable and a shared library. To fix this upgrade to `file` version `5.36` or above.

Comment: Yep, thanks, I updated `file` and it seems ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executables compiled with `-pie` *are* shared objects. `file` now has special support to deal with these. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/why-does-gcc-create-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary-according-to) go into this in more detail.

Comment: Vote to close the question as a duplicate instead of linking to another question.

Comment: Will do in the future. Thanks!