# How to determine what is in the address Assembly is calling

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

I'm trying to decipher simple Assembly code, but I'm not very experienced in the language. If I have the following block of code in main:

```
 push   %ebp
 8048a45:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048a47:       53                      push   %ebx
 8048a48:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048a4b:       83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
 8048a4e:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048a51:       8b 5d 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%ebx
 8048a54:       83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
 8048a57:       75 0c                   jne    8048a65 <main+0x21>
 8048a59:       a1 c4 d7 04 08          mov    0x804d7c4,%eax ??
 8048a5e:       a3 f0 d7 04 08          mov    %eax,0x804d7f0 ??
 8048a63:       eb 74                   jmp    8048ad9 <main+0x95>
 8048a65:       83 f8 02                cmp    $0x2,%eax
 8048a68:       75 49                   jne    8048ab3 <main+0x6f>
 8048a6a:       c7 44 24 04 e8 a2 04    movl   $0x804a2e8,0x4(%esp)
```

On lines 8048a59 and 048a5e, where I've put the question marks, I'm assuming it's trying to set whatever is in address 0x804d7f0 to what is in address 0x804d7c4, but how do I know what specifically is in those addresses?

Comment: You don't if you don't know what the program is and what it is doing.

Comment: If you can get the linker to spit out a map file, you should get a list of all absolute addresses for your variables.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you'll need to determine to which section corresponds this address. You can do this with objdump like this `objdump -h`

Then you can disassemble section you interested in like its done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685483/how-can-i-examine-contents-of-a-data-section-of-an-elf-file-on-linux).

[Here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/09/objdump-examples/) some useful information about viewing sections and their addresses.

Other way is to use run time debugger and just print out memory e.g. `x addr` for gdb.

---

P.S. if you like to recover variable name, it may be impossible because compiler usually removes that kind of information for most symbols.

Comment: Use `objdump -d -r` to print symbol info ("Relocations") for addresses, when it's available.  It tacks on a comment like `# 61d0c8 <stderr+0xa88>`.  Beware of cases like this where it's really nothing to do with stderr, just that was the nearest symbol still present in the final binary.  It works a lot better on `.o` files than executables, since the linker hasn't yet thrown away symbol info for non-global static data.

Comment: I actually use `alias disas='objdump -drwC -Mintel'`, to do that, de-mangle C++ names, and use Intel-style syntax.  (And not line-wrap the machine code for long instructions).